# Стал доступен второй черновик нового Code of Conduct

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, правила

В июле были опубликованы две последовательные черновые версии нового документа, который должен полностью заменить собой существующую политику «be-nice» («будьте дружелюбными»):

- [первая версия](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1G1BpL_G_m6F5LIPMUZVcLejSPFTb3XbI_69X8fQSZAk), собравшая в [тематической теме на Метамете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312038/357761) большое количество отзывов;
- [вторая версия](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1sgEOl4wP4CIO0rodsplP15_U10bjE3RlMCkA_jI4cMc), полученная по результатам этих отзывов, и по которой также идёт сбор обратной связи в [новой тематической теме на Метамете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312850/357761).

Ниже приведён перевод второй версии черновика, версии R7-V2 ([архивная ссылка](https://yadi.sk/i/Q2A9a8Pz3ZcVzM)).

***Важное замечание:*** так как ряд понятий из текста не имеет однозначного перевода на русский язык (например, Code of Conduct — это и кодекс, и нормы поведения), данный текст необходимо рассматривать как адаптацию, пока не будет выполнена его коллективная редактура.

> ## Нормы поведения (Code of Conduct) на Stack Exchange — версия 2, ревизия 7 (R7-V2)
>
> *Это обновлённая версия норм поведения, составленная на основе [отзывов с Меты](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312038), бесед с участниками и анкетирования пользователей. Данные нормы впоследствии заменят собой справочный раздел «[Будьте дружелюбными](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)». Мы приветствуем любую обратную связь. Крайне желательно оставить свои отзывы [[на Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312850) — прим. пер.] до 27 июля.*
>
> **Настоящие Нормы поведения призваны помочь в построении образовательного сообщества, основанного на доброжелательности, сотрудничестве и взаимном уважении.** Вне зависимости от того, пришли ли вы сюда с вопросом или чтобы поделиться своими знаниями, мы призываем присоединиться к процессу построения сообщества, где рады каждому, и где каждый может принять участие вне зависимости от уровня знаний и личностных черт.
>
> Мы обязуемся обеспечивать соблюдение и улучшение данных Норм. Их действие распространяется на каждого участника $CommunityName$ и сайтов сети Stack Exchange, включая нашу команду, модераторов¹ и любого, кто оставляет сообщения на сайтах вопросов и ответов и в чате.
>
> **Ожидаемое поведение:**
>
> - **Если вы пришли за помощью, не препятствуйте желающим помочь вам.** Комментарии других участников к вашему вопросу не являются чем-то плохим — они нацелены на то, чтобы сделать вопрос полезным как можно большему количеству людей.
> - **Если вы пришли помочь другим, будьте терпеливыми и приветливыми.** Изучение всех норм и принципов работы Stack Overflow — сложная задача, особенно для новичков. Если вы заметили, что кто-то испытывает трудности или нуждается в помощи — помогите ему.
> - **Благосклонно воспринимайте отзывы других и не скупитесь на отзывы сами.** Обратная связь с участниками — основа нашей культуры. Качественная обратная связь звучит уважительно по отношению к получателю, чёткая и конструктивная.
> - **Будьте доброжелательными.** Проявляйте вежливость и дружелюбность по отношению к другим. Избегайте подтрунивания и сарказма — письменная речь плохо передаёт тон высказывания. Если же обстоятельства будят в вас гнев, не вступайте в разговор вовсе.
>
> **Неприемлемое поведение:**
>
> - **Никаких резких замечаний или оскорблений.** Какими бы ни были намерения, такое поведение может плохо повлиять на других участников.
>
>   **Не дружелюбно → Дружелюбно:**
>
>   - «Это гуглится за пять секунд.» → «Это называется Лоренц-инвариантность/-ковариантность. Поищите в интернете статьи на эту тему — они помогут намного больше, нежели можем мы здесь, в комментариях.»
>   - «Не думаю, что это дубликат. Не лезь с закрытием, если не разбираешься в теме.» → «Это не дубликат. Мой вопрос о цементных плитах, тогда как предложенный вами вопрос — о гипсокартоне.»
>   - «Вы вообще понимаете по-русски? Если нет, то ничем не могу помочь.» → «Правильно ли я понимаю, что вы хотите узнать, как добавить swap-раздел после установки ОС?»
>   - «Я задал вопрос не для того, чтобы его редактировали.» → «Спасибо за уточняющую правку. Я готов добавить любую необходимую для получения ответа информацию.»
> - **Никаких оскорблений и личных нападок.** Рассматривайте не самого человека, а то, что он пишет. Не переходите на личности (примеры: «лентяй», «дремучий»), даже когда есть за что.
> - **Никакой нетерпимости.** Недопустимы любые высказывания, направленные на то, чтобы обидеть или сделать человека чужим на основании его расы, пола, сексуальной ориентации, религии и т. д. Если ваше высказывание находится на грани — лучше не публиковать его.
> - **Никаких притеснений.** Сюда, в частности, входят: травля, запугивание, нецензурная брань, прямые и завуалированные угрозы, высказывания сексуального характера, неприличное и бестактное поведение, а также постоянное встревание не по теме.
>
> **Подача жалоб и применение мер**
>
> Каждый участник делает посильный вклад в поддержание атмосферы доброжелательности и взаимоуважения в сообществе. Если вы встретились с проявлением неприемлемого поведения по отношению к себе или другим, можно:
>
> - [Отметить его тревогой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/flagging). В зависимости от типа нарушения тревога либо привлечёт модераторов, либо выполнит автоматическое удаление.
> - [Связаться с нами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact). Мы постараемся ответить как можно скорее.
>
> Мы серьёзно относимся к каждой жалобе. К тем, кто не выполняет добросовестно пункты настоящих Норм поведения, модераторы принимают меры, достаточные с их точки зрения. Типовой сценарий обработки тревог выглядит следующим образом:
>
> - **Предупреждение.** В случае первого нарушения модераторы, как правило, просто удаляют сообщение и высылают предупреждение. В большинстве случаев нарушения от конкретного участника больше не повторяются.
> - **Временная блокировка.** При притеснениях, нетерпимости, оскорблениях либо повторных нарушениях модераторы накладывают временную блокировку на учётную запись (от суток и более, в зависимости от вида нарушения).
> - **Вечная блокировка.** В крайне редких случаях модераторы изгоняют из сообщества участников, упорно проявляющих дестабилизирующее и деструктивное поведение.
>
> Все меры принимаются индивидуально и на усмотрение модераторов. Если вы сомневаетесь в верности принятого модератором решения [свяжитесь с нами напрямую](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact).
>
> ---
>
> Мы создали Нормы поведения для закладывания фундамента взаимоуважения, которое участники ожидают друг от друга. Также он задаёт то, чего мы, развиваясь, должны придерживаться *[буквальный перевод: «... они задают своего рода дорогу, которой должна придерживаться наша культура, и куда её надо выправлять при её сходе на обочину» — прим. пер.]*.
>
> Мы рады любым отзывам как на эти нормы, так и на другие аспекты нашей деятельности в Stack Overflow. Благодарим вас за участие в совместном построении доброжелательного образовательного сообщества, основанного на взаимоуважении.
>
> *Вышеприведённый текст включает в себя идеи и термины из правил поведения на сайтах [Coral Project](https://coralproject.net/code-of-conduct/), [Buffer](https://open.buffer.com/code-of-conduct/) и [Tech Solidarity](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dy-hFbKGmwqRz8qIKi1Hpxy6SC04xAH2WJ9d-p5C1nA/edit#heading=h.12m28fxbmn5n).*
>
> ---
>
> <sup>¹ Модераторы — это избранные или назначенные участники, помогающие с управлением сообществом. Подробнее описано в статье справки «[Кто такие модераторы и какова их роль?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)»</sup>

Comment: Глобально говорить, что сарказм это плохо считаю некорректным. Стоило бы выделить, например, сарказм в виде неправильного и вредного ответа на вопрос, сарказм несущий под собой оскорбление пользователя. Оба этих варианта, очевидно, вредны и недопустимы. Такие вещи и сейчас флагаются и удаляются (по крайней мере это разумно). В сарказме как таковом плохого ничего не вижу, для излишний параноиков можно приписать <sarcasm/>

Comment: Я так понимаю, цель данной публикации на данной момент не полировка перевода(ибо черновик), а обсуждение самого Кодекса?

Comment: @vp_arth Да. Думаю, бессмысленно пока тратить коллективные усилия на то, что может измениться.

Comment: Вообще говоря, несмотря на то, что с *буквой* кодекса можно долго спорить,  его *дух* вполне понятен. Любой, кто не согласен с ним(с духом), либо враг сообщества(тролль, которого кодекс лишает пищи), либо "перестраховщик"(участник, который переживает за чрезмерные притеснения)... На первых можно забить, а вторым таки необходимо дать опору, некие гарантии отсутствия злоупотребления...

Comment: @yolosora, вы не одиноки в своём мнении. [С Метаметы](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312922/357761): *Sarcasm are simply a tone of levity that is part of the Q/A and chat culture we participate in. I think it better to say "No bigoted/raciest/sexist jokes/sarcasm". As many jokes and sarcastic remarks can be fun for all and not abusive in the least. So instead of avoiding all jokes/sarcasm we should avoid the harmful kind. ... It hurts no one it is not targeted at a person but serves to point out that under this rule the chat would be rather boring and people would eventually leave.*