# Стоит ли нам полностью запретить иронию и сарказм на сайте?

Tags: обсуждение, нормы-поведения

В продолжении темы грядущего по всей сети обновления правила be nice (см. [Стал доступен второй черновик нового Code of Conduct](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7552/213987)).

Я бы хотел вынести в отдельное обсуждение вот какой вопрос.

<s>Похоже, что,</s>     <s>Мне и нескольким участникам, от лица которых я говорю</s>     В новом кодексе *похоже* предлагается запретить полностью такие вещи, как иронию и сарказм:

> Будьте доброжелательными. Проявляйте вежливость и дружелюбность по
>   отношению к другим. **Избегайте подтрунивания и сарказма** (выделение
>   моё - А К) — письменная речь плохо передаёт тон высказывания. Если же
>   обстоятельства будят в вас гнев, не вступайте в разговор вовсе.

В оригинале:

> Be kind. Be polite and friendly with others. Avoid jokes and sarcasm
>   -- tone is hard to decipher online. If a situation makes it hard to act kindly, stop engaging and move on.

Что именно я хотел бы обсудить и что оставить за рамками.

Во-первых, меня интересует возможное правоприменение этой нормы. Является ли это рекомендацией, которой неплохо бы следовать или это является неприемлемым применением, когда любой ироничный комментарий под вопросом будет по первому же флагу удален, а автор комментария уйдёт на некоторое время в бан?

Я понимаю, что данный CoC ещё не принят, но меня интересует, каким образом будут трактовать данные правила как модераторы, которые будут обязаны соблюдать букву закона и какая позиция будет у широких масс по отношению к данному правилу.

Во-вторых, я слышал некоторые осторожные голоса разных участников, которые говорили, что убрав из общения иронию мы очень сильно иссушаем нашу речь и общаться на *таком* stackoverflow для них будет намного менее интересно. Я слышал подобные высказывания как от англоязычных участников (см. в [комментарии Arhad отсылку](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7552/%d0%a1%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-code-of-conduct#comment31028_7552)), так и у нас на русскоязычном сообществе. С учётом того, что в последнее время широко распространилась мысль, что "участники ничего не решают, администрация как скажет - так и будет" я вижу, что мало желающих подымать это обсуждение.

Однако вопрос является достаточно важным: если значительная часть участников будет разочарована в проекте - то это повод подумать, насколько стоит вводить такие поспешные правила и продумать заранее, не выйдет ли "улучшение" боком.

Есть ли среди нас люди, кто может компетентно пояснить, в каких случаях ирония приносит больше выгоды общению, а когда является вредной?

В-третьих, я бы пожалуй убрал из этой темы обсуждение, каким образом придти к отмене данного правила. У меня сложилось впечатление, что даже если весь русскоязычный актив придёт на метамету - наши голоса просто утонут в общей массе; также мы обсуждали есть ли необходимость у локализованных сайтов сети иметь правила, корректирующие глобальный rule set - но формально есть два возражения. Во-первых, CoC ещё не принят - смысл пытаться изменить правило, если его ещё нет (преждевременная оптимизиация). Во-вторых, не факт, что мы в этой теме решим, что стоит иронию разрешать. Так что пока я бы просто предложил сосредоточиться именно на самой сути вопроса.

PS Голосовалок не будет, прошу высказываться индивидуально.

Update от 12 августа. Коллеги! В теме есть ответ от одного из весьма уважаемых избранных модераторов, я бы хотел выделить этот ответ из текущих подняв наверх его галкой. Мне кажется, что этот ответ стоит почитать, потому что хотя он подписан конкретным человеком - но является выражением мнением всего модстава "сарказм не запрещается".

Сам я являюсь противником ставить на мете галки в дискуссионных вопросах, в которых спрашивается мнение многих участников; галки в них возможно стоило ставить лишь на ответах КМ или на тех ответах на которые попросит КМ.

Тем не менее, уважая мнение каждого кто высказался -- огромное спасибо за ваши мнения и в отсутствие поста Николаса, я рискну пока что поставить галку на ответе @PashaPash.

Comment: Попытка убрать эмоциональную составляющую из текста обречена на провал. Администрация может принимать какие угодно правила, но сарказм и иронию из сообщений убрать не удастся — не в этом мире. С другой стороны, есть сильно «ироничные» и «саркастичные» личности, которые лепят свой сарказм куда надо и куда не надо, но, на мой взгляд, это и сейчас будет удалено. Не вижу причин для введения новых правил. А если что-то форрмально и введут, то это ровным счётом ничего не изменит.

Comment: Перевод, кстати, не совсем верный. Правильнее будет "Избегайте ***шуток*** и сарказма — письменная речь плохо передаёт тон высказывания. Если же в обстоятельствах ***вам трудно быть дружелюбным***, не вступайте в разговор вовсе."

Comment: Конечно же, **ДА!!!**

Comment: Tim Post♦: I think we're likely to go with "avoid sarcasm, be careful with jokes" .. but nothing is carved in stone yet. We can't take jokes away, a chief complaint is that the site isn't human enough. So we should probably just be more specific that we're afraid of disastrous jokes by just cautioning folks to be careful .. but we'll see. Thanks for chewing on that, I wasn't quite happy with the wording either. (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312850/the-second-draft-of-our-code-of-conduct-is-available-for-feedback-and-review/312922#comment1025077_312855)

Comment: Вот щас запретим иронию с сарказмом, и все резко станут такие белые и пушистые и атмосфера абсолютно дружелюбная, ага :)

Comment: А о чем собственно, обсуждение? Насколько я вижу, фраза про _"Avoid jokes and sarcasm"_ есть и в [нынешней версии](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct), тут ровным счетом ничего не поменялось. Зато возникает другой вопрос, относительно _"Be polite"_. Не значит ли это, что обращение на "ты" тоже будет считаться bannable offence?

Comment: Оно ведь как... Всегда есть обходные пути.  "Сэр председатель, будет ли нарушением регламента, если я назову сэра Джона подлецом и мерзавцем?" - "Да, конечно, назвав сэра Джона подлецом и мерзавцем, вы нарушите регламент!" - "Спасибо, сэр! Тогда я не стану называть сэра Джона подлецом и мерзавцем!"

Comment: Ну вот как [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/866700/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d1%8b) обойтись без иронии и сарказма? :)

Comment: @Harry да это ж самый очевиднейший тролль, а все и рады, бросились блистать остроумием? 0_0

Comment: @Anatol Ну так здесь так мало развлечений... Последнее хотят отобрать... :)

Comment: @Harry может стоит оглядеться и найти себе другие развлечения? инженер неплохо зарабатывает (как правило) и может позволить себе всякое, попробуйте :)

Comment: @Anatol Я не инженер :)

Comment: Обсуждать аннигиляцию остроумия на стаке это как обсуждать вынос телевизора из сортира - вещь приятная, но тут совершенно ненужна. К томуже я мнительный зануда с крошечными социальными навыками (за оскорбления самого себя меня же не забанят?), потому я сарказмом всёравно пользоваться не умею и лютобешено завидую видя тех, кто умеет. Так что я полностью за это правило. Стак должен стать ещё как минимум на 20% скучнее!

Comment: Предлагаю не превращать этот ресурс в уголовный кодекс )

Comment: @ДанисХамидуллин, честно говоря, я даже не понимаю, этот недоответ выражает позицию "запретить" или "разрешить". Его надо либо дополнить, либо превратить в комментарий. UPDATE: Раз реакции не последовало, превращаю в комментарий.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Сарказм и шутки не запрещают, новых норм не вводят, в правилах ничего не меняется.

Собственно, вся проблема сводится к тому, что следующее предположение не соответствует действительности.

> Я бы хотел вынести в отдельное обсуждение вот какой вопрос. В новом кодексе предлагается **запретить полностью** такие вещи, как иронию и сарказм:

Вот дословная цитата из Code of Conduct:

> Be kind and friendly.
>   **Avoid** sarcasm and **be careful** with jokes — tone is hard to decipher online. If a situation makes it hard to be friendly, stop participating and move on.

Это вполне разумное утверждение - некоторые шутки и некоторые саркастические замечания могут быть довольно обидными. Но слово avoid, и тем более be careful, ну никак не тянет на полный запрет.

Простая аналогия

> "Осторожнее при переходе улицы, избегайте перехода улицы в оживленных местах"

и

> "Улицу переходить **полностью запрещено**".

Первому учат в школе (и даже в детском саду), это полностью разумное утверждение. Но это не значит что нам с детского сада запрещают переходить улицы.

Если кто-то вдруг выйдет на улицу с ПДД, будет их цитировать и кричать "нам запрещают переходить дороги! правительство угнетает пешеходов!" - вы вряд ли его поддержите. Но по какой-то странно причине точно такое же поведение находит поддержку на мете ruSO, прямо в этом вопросе :)

---

Пожалуйста, не забывайте, что наша цель - создать атмосферу дружелюбия, и спокойно пообсуждать в ней технические вопросы. А не подвергнуть репрессиям тех, что шутит шутки.

Решения в случае тревог по нарушению Code Of Conduct принимают модераторы, вручную - и они при этом рассматривают каждую ситуацию и всегда учитывают контекст. А не просто идут по чеклисту "шутка, сарказм - виноват!".

Comment: "Осторожнее при переходе улицы, избегайте перехода улицы в оживленных местах" За это штрафуют, так что это не рекомендация, а правило (:

Comment: @Suvitruf штрафуют только при переходе в неположенном месте (при наличии положенного в непосредственной близости). это абстракция, она должна быть дырявой

Comment: @Suvitruf некоторые проявления сарказма (оскорбительные) - наказуемы. Некоторые переходы улиц (в неположенном месте при наличии положенного где-то рядом) - наказуемы. Но цель - наказать не за переход, а за то, что при этом вы подвергли опасности жизнь/здоровье других людей (например, водителя, который попытается вас объехать)

Comment: Цель - наказать, а не перевоспитать?

Comment: @Suvitruf в случае перехода улицы - государство пошло по схеме прикладного бихевиоризма, и именно наказывает, считая что это вызовет перевоспитание. В случае SO - с "нарушителем" просто поговорят и попытаться донести,  в чем именно он не прав,  и почему его поведение наносит вред - многие, на самом деле,  оскорбляют людей из лучших побуждений. Как бы странно это не звучало

Comment: Т.е, ничего не поменялось, просто появилась бесполезная строка в рекомендация, чтоб обидчивые успокоились?

Comment: @Suvitruf да. вот примерное обоснование переписывания: "Some people wanted more detail and examples (for clarity), others wanted less (for broader applicability)." (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312038/).

Answer (score 27):

Лично я очень хотел бы, чтобы негрубая форма иронии/сарказма/шуток была разрешена.

Те же классические комментарии про телепатов в отпуске, неформальные сравнения с какими-то не-it-шными примерами ([пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/619440/178988)) довольно важны для создания атмосферы и не наносят никакого вреда ресурсу или участникам.

Comment: WTF "разрешена"?! Кто Вам, свободному человеку, может это запретить?

Comment: Лично я против "телепатов в отпуске", потому что это заезженный штамп, который оскорбляет мое чувство прекрасного. Хочешь острить - будь добр это делать как следует, а не на уровне Петросяна.

Comment: @Igor, WTF где-то на гране и скорее нет, чем да. А телепаты никого не оскорбляют.

Comment: Хм, пардон, нечетко выразился. Я не спрашивал, разрешено ли выражение "What the fuck?". Я хотел сказать: "Какого черта кому-то может потребоваться разрешение на иронию/сарказм/шутки?".

Comment: @Igor, ну так вроде бы об этом и весь вопрос, что не надо запрещать. Возможность бана никто не отменял, так что написать можно что угодно, но только 4 раза ;)

Comment: «классические комментарии про телепатов в отпуске» — это классическое оскорбление, которого на сайте быть не должно.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, с каких пор «ТВО» стало оскорблением? У меня создаётся впечатление, что у Вас неадекватное восприятие текста.

Comment: @ixSci На самом деле, с первого дня этого проекта! Возможно, я что–то понимаю неверно, как и любой другой человек. Это не отменяет факт, что подобные фразы (1) воспринимаются отрицательно адресатами, (2) всегда удалялись с этого сайта. Проблема в том, что это фраза неоднозначна. То ли вы хотите подшутить, то ли запрашиваете информацию. Хотите больше данных? Пожалуйста, напишите об этом в явном виде, например, «Добавьте в ваш вопрос то и это, без этого ничего не ясно.». Хотите жестоко подшутить? [Оно того не стоит](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-friendly). :)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, смотрите, банальная фраза (комментарий): «покажите код, телепаты в отпуске». Что в ней оскорбительного? Да, можно обойтись без приписки, но как наличие оной кого-то оскорбляет? Здесь «телепаты в отпуске», это просто сокращение от: «мы не можем ничего сказать по поводу Вашего вопроса без наличия дополнительных данных». Это, на мой взгляд, вполне безобидная фраза, которая любым адекватным человеком воспринимается нормально.

Comment: @ixSci Есть дружеская улыбка, а есть недовольный оскал. Вроде выглядит одинаково, но смысл совершенно разный. И каждый поймет, что есть что. Фраза про телепатов — издевка, колкость. Если лично вам, как ее автору, она кажется «уместной», это не означает, что она не заденет адресата. Хоть вы оба и на одной странице одного сайта, вы находитесь в совершенно разных социальных контекстах. Для адресата такие фразы — это всегда оскал.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, Вы излишне категоричны и склонны к обобщениям. Для меня это не оскал, с какой стороны я бы не находился. И в этом я вижу проблему, я считаю, что Ваше восприятие текста неадекватно его содержанию, оно чрезвычайно «нежное». В таком случае, считаю, что Ваша компетентность в оценке таких вопросов находится под вопросом. Ради интереса, сейчас поспрашиваю отношение к этой фразе в чате — на мете его уже явно показали (плюсы к этому ответу).

Comment: @ixSci Обоснования для разрешения колкостей тем, что вы считаете не компетентным всех, кто с вами не согласен, не котируются. Я не вижу ни одного обоснования, почему мы должны не удалять подобные комментарии. «Мне ок» — не обоснование. Обоснование против в том, что это колкость (написал выше). Пожалуйста, подкрепите вашу точку зрения рассуждением, а не толпой единомышленников.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ваше субъективное имеет место быть, оно важно! Как мне кажется, было бы здорово в обсуждении на Мете, в ответах, добавить чуть больше чем просто личные переживания. Пожалуйста, обоснуйте необходимость колкостей для создания атмосферы? Какую именно атмосферу колкостями вы пытаетесь создать? Почему такие фразы уместны на сайте, цель которого минимизация всего, что не относится к сути вопроса или его ответам?

Comment: @ixSci плюсы к этому ответу - это не обязательно плюсы в поддержку именно фразы про телепатов. IMHO, фраза действительно петросянство, из той же категории что "в гугле забанили?" и "религия не позволяет"?

Comment: @PashaPash, тем не менее эти фразы (особенно «религия не позволяет») довольно часто используются в русскоязычной среде. Я не ратую за их использования, но и в осуждении не вижу смысла.

Comment: @ixSci фраза про религию - просто невежливая, с оттенком хамства (IMHO). мат и эфемизмы тоже часто используются в русскоязычной среде (и мной в оффлайне, например). вопрос в том, стоит ли тянуть это на SO.

Comment: Ради всего святого! Перестаньте использовать слово "маты" во множественном числе! *"Я упал на пыльные маты и заплакал."*

Comment: @Igor насчет числа матов - это на Русский Язык.

Comment: @PashaPash Я сейчас перейду на сарказм и оскорбления.

Comment: @Igor не стоит. злоупотребил правами модератора и исправил свой комментарий :)

Comment: @PashaPash Огромное спасибо! (без сарказма)

Answer (score 22):

Мне не кажется правильным запрещать иронию и сарказм. Шутки вполне уместны, и создают атмосферу человечности.

Я бы ослабил это правило до такого:

> - Не будьте злыми
> - Старайтесь не демотивировать участников, особенно новичков, ЕСЛИ видите желание разобраться
> - Используйте шутки и иронию с оглядкой на то, что они могут оказаться обидными
> - Категорически избегайте личных выпадов

Comment: Любопытно, но за эти же критерии мы критикуем КМ :) Кто будет решать что "желание есть разбираться" или "что является личным выпадом"?

Comment: @Other: Автор текста, конечно, и только он.

Comment: Эм... что? Если кто-то матерится и для него мат - это норма, но, по Вашему, его текст будет легален, т. к. он не видит в нём проблем?

Comment: @Other: Тогда он подпадёт под правило «мат нельзя».

Comment: Выкрутились. Ладно, а если кто-то скажет "отхер" и для него это будет уморительная шуточка, то, т. к. он автор, это пропустят?

Comment: @Other Ну, или бинайс для всех, или ни для кого.

Answer (score 8):

Доколе, комрады...

Сначала нам [запрещают уважительно общаться (даже удаляют такие сообщения)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6666/15479), теперь пытаются вырвать из общения довольно важную составляющую. Что дальше?

Тут товарищ Kromster привёл примеры, которые ошибочно посчитал сарказмом:

> Ну как так можно не знать что такое АБС, вас совсем не учат в БСД
>   чтоли?

Это насмешка, а не сарказм. Такие комментарии, в принципе, и сейчас выпиливаются по тревоге.

Или, быть может, это я не правильно трактую сие дело? Понимаете?

В данном вопросе интересует **трактовка** понятия "сарказм". Сарказм, он как бы не несёт априори негативного оттенка, это просто речевой оборот. Я вообще не понимаю, почему это стоит отдельным пунктом в обсуждениях на метамете. Все случаи негативного использования сарказма/иронии - это, как правило, насмешка/оскорбление, которые и так выпиливаются.

Учитывая всю эту манию с бинайсом, я вообще боюсь представить куда эта цензура приведёт нас.

Comment: куда куда... к резиновым женщинам, невкусному пиву и неинтересному stackoverflow.

Comment: @AK "стерильному SO", я бы сказал.

Comment: То есть с одной стороны вы говорите что насмешки, сарказм и ирония и так выпиливаются. А с другой - против того, чтобы это было зафиксировано в правилах? о_0 И можно, плиз, привести пример позитивного сарказма?

Comment: @Kromster выпиливаются оскорбления и т.п, а не сарказм. "Телепаты в отпуске" - вот позитивный широко используемый пример сарказма.

Comment: Само по себе "телепаты в отпуске" это вы чуточку потешили свое ЧСВ, поленились помочь человеку и немного его оскорбили. CoC вам и говорит (в текущей редакции), - пройти мимо, вместо нанесения малого вреда. Вот представьте, пришли вы в автомастерскую, "у меня в машине при повороте хрустит что-то", а вас пошлют с формулировкой "телепаты в отпуске". Это будет конструктивно? Или правильнее если у вас уточнять начнут, при езде это, и какая у вас модель машины, и давно ли шрусы меняли .. и вообще вдруг дадут ссылку на справку по задаванию вопросов в автосервисах - всяко полезнее ;-)

Comment: @Kromster 1) вы сравниваете сервис, который за услуги перед деньги и портал, где люди помогают на добровольной основе? 2) более правильная аналогия по контексту была тогда уж "Ой, у меня машина сломалась".

Comment: @Suvitruf я привел вам пример. Надеюсь вы его поняли. Замените сервис на соседа Борю, или волонтеров. Дело не в платности или бесплатности, а в знании предметной области и ЧСВ. Здесь никто никого не заставляет помогать (если вас заставляют - моргните два раза). Суть в том, что рекомендуют, так же, и не вредить (сколь мал бы этот вред вам не казался, но на SO *как-то* выявили, что сарказм не есть полезная форма помощи).

Comment: @Kromster как комментарий целиком, "телепаты" и правда будут неуместной шуткой. Но что насчет такого варианта: *"Не могли бы вы предоставить стектрейс исключения? А то единственный телепат недавно в отпуск ушел, а без него не получается определить где же у вас там ошибка возникла."*.

Comment: @Kromster за такой комментарий тоже банить или как?

Comment: @Kromster, «телепаты в отпуске» это начало диалога, который может привести к тому, что автор улучшит свой вопрос и на него можно будет дать ответ. «Пройти мимо» ничего автору не скажет и вопрос не улучшит. Считаю, что «ТВО» не является ни сарказмом, ни иронией. Сарказм это вообще тонкая штука и люди зачастую не понимают, что есть он, а что он не есть. В общем, сарказм и иронию довольно сложно распознать без интонации либо же хорошего знания собеседника.

Comment: А что делать если телепаты не в отпуске? И эксперт таки выдаёт решение на основе недостаточных данных? Просто с комментарием, указывающим на этот недостаток..

Comment: Часто «сарказмом» прикрывают глупость. Человек сморозил глупость, а потом начинает плести, что это был сарказм.

Comment: Глупость - это и есть глупость. А заявление, что это "видите ли был сарказм" - ещё большая глупость)

Comment: @PavelMayorov или как. Но согласитесь, "Не могли бы вы предоставить стектрейс исключения? Без него не получается определить где же у вас там ошибка возникла." звучит явно позитивнее

Comment: @ixSci Одинокое "ТВО" означает начало диалога для нас с вами, а для новичка, который не может сформулировать вопрос это означает чуть более чем ничего, и его ответ будет "Что вы имеете ввиду?" если он вежлив, или "да не пошли бы все эти кто советовал на SO вопросы задавать". Неодинокое ТВО, как в коменте выше, реальной пользы не несет.

Comment: Опять эти сюсюканья с новичками. Если он от невинной иронии так агрится, то вряд ли на SO останется надолго в любом случае.

Comment: @Suvitruf кому невинная ирония (нам то с вами за 20к репы каждому в сумме, и лет по 30 жизни за плечами, не такое видели и слышали), а кому и оскорбление. При том что повторюсь, ирония эта кому какую пользу несет, кроме маленького смешка написавшему её?

Comment: @Kromster я не вижу в этом никакой насмешки. Если человек на это обижается, то может проблема в нём?

Comment: @Kromster вот только если выбрать "самую позитивную" форму из всех возможных - сайт превратится в написанный роботами. Надо не сравнивать разные формы друг с другом - а разделять их на допустимые и недопустимые.

Comment: @Kromster, одинокое ТВО это мусор, который нужно удалять. ТВО в контексте не несёт никакого смысла, согласен. Так же как «спасибо», «пожалуйста» и прочие «бесполезные» слова, которые эмоционально окрашивают сообщение. Но без них общаться люди не любят! (бесполезный восклицательный знак)

Comment: @Suvitruf напишите плиз, какую конкретно пользу несет ТВО в примере выше? Чем комментарий без ТВО стал хуже, и почему бы нам тогда в противном случае не добавить ТВО ко всем комментариям сходного толку, для того чтобы сделать их лучше и ламповее

Comment: Но не из комментариев же, которые эфемерны по природе.

Comment: Прицепились ведь к этому ТВО. Но, как видите, даже он вопросы вызывает. Что уж говорить про "сарказм" в целом.

Comment: @Kromster если выбор между ТВО и игнорированием вопроса, то я за ТВО.

Comment: @Suvitruf люблю предметные обсуждения, а не абстракнтное обсуждение бинайс когда у каждого свое представление и понятие ) Дисклеймер - конечно же все это оттенки серого и целиком запрещать ничего нереально и не стоит, но все же сдвинуть спектр чуть-чуть в сторону дружелюбия было бы хорошо.

Comment: @Kromster о5 25. Откуда вообще растут ноги у "нужно быть дружелюбней"? По-моему, ru SO и так дружелюбный дальше не куда. Проявления недружелюбия в рамках допустимой погрешности.

Comment: Согласен, куда дружелюбнее? У нас тут не детский сад, а собрание инженеров.

Comment: @Suvitruf Предлагаю рассматривать выбор по шкале между одиноким ТВО, ТВО+подсказкой, подсказкой и ничем. Одинокий ТВО плох, подсказка однозначно хороша, ничто - ничто, ТВО+подсказка - скорее хороша, но ТВО ее несколько оттеняет плохим. Итого CoC рекоммендует воздерживаться от ТВО, т.к. оно не несет пользы.

Comment: @ixSci "У нас тут не детский сад, а собрание инженеров" И что, давайте как на заводе, матами изъясняться - настойщими профи станем?

Comment: @Kromster рекомендовать они могут что угодно. Но если я не буду следовать рекомендации, будут какие-то меры? "И что, давайте как на заводе, матами изъясняться - настойщими профи станем". Вы из крайности в крайность скачете =/ Я вообще не видел, чтоб тут кто-то матами изъяснялся.

Comment: @Kromster, маты не маты, но, насколько я помню, одни из лучших спецов на Vingrad были не шибко вежливые. Мешало ли это мне? Обижался ли я? Для меня важны были знания и я подстраивался под отвечающих, потому что они мне были нужны, а не я им. Чувствуете разницу?

Comment: @Suvitruf CoC задает общее направление, вектор. Про меры - это не ко мне вопрос. Я лишь аргументирую за вектор, что мне он понятен и, хоть я с ним и не совсем согласен, все же он полезнее, чем вреднее. В меру своих сил, на примерах, пробую и другим показать, что польза от этого есть. Я очень рад, что матами не изъясняемся на SO и вот из-за таких спецов, который ixSci упомянул, я во многом и не форумчанин Винграда и схожих площадок.

Comment: @ixSci *"Согласен, куда дружелюбнее?"* - два примера выше было, *куда* дружелюбнее - порицание одиночных ТВО, и избегание ТВО в комментарии где ТВО не несет пользы.

Comment: @Kromster, рафинирование высказываний не делает их дружелюбнее, оно делает их эмоционально пустыми. Я живой человек, у меня есть эмоции, и я иногда их показываю.

Comment: @ixSci рафинирование высказываний от сарказма и т.п. **делает** их дружелюбнее. А эмоциональная полнота может быть показана не только сарказмом и иронией. Я бы за это не волновался.

Comment: @Kromster, я думаю, что мы поняли позиции друг друга. Я с Вами не согласен по этим пунктам, и переубедить меня Вам не удастся, как и мне Вас, я полагаю.

Comment: Всё это от того, что для нас с @ixSci это не просто БЗ. Отвечают и спрашивают конкретные люди, с конкретным характером. Если все будут писать "по линейке", то это убьёт общение совсем в ноль.

Comment: @Suvitruf *"Отвечают и спрашивают конкретные люди, с конкретным характером"* вот я бы не хотел, чтобы вопрос или ответ на технический вопрос пестрел "характером" отвечающего. (И к счастью SO этим практически не грешит, кроме пары участников"). У меня конкретная техническая проблема к которой мне нужно конкретное правильное(!) техническое решение.

Comment: @Kromster да, в вопросах и ответах "характер" неуместен. В отличии от комментариев.

Comment: @Kromster "Маты" - в спортзале.

Comment: @Igor "спортзалы" - в школах. А что вы собственно имеете ввиду?

Comment: @Kromster Веду свою маленькую войну против деградации русского языка ).

Comment: @Igor так что вы собственно имеете ввиду, надо как-то иначе написать, правильнее, как?

Comment: @Kromster У слова "мат" (в смысле - ругательства) нет множественного числа. По крайней мере - не было, когда я был маленьким.

Comment: @Igor ясно. Хорошо

Comment: @ixSci *...я подстраивался под отвечающих, потому что они мне были нужны, а не я им...* - а теперь хотите навязать эту же модель поведения последующим поколениям? получили статус/знания/опыт, натерпевшись грубостей, и теперь хотите вести себя так же, унижать, показывая свою значимость? в армии это называется дедовщиной.

Comment: @Anatol, читайте, что я пишу (если уж решили мне что-то ответить), а свои _необоснованные_ выводы оставьте при себе.

Comment: @ixSci я прочитал все до единого комментарии и не только под этим постом. сарказма не поняли разве?

Comment: @Anatol, сарказм невозможно распознать не слыша тон и/или не зная собеседника. Я Вас не слышу и вижу впервые. Да и нет там никакого сарказма.

Comment: @ixSci, нет, Вы хорошо поищите. (иронизирую)

Comment: @Anatol у вас плохо выходит.

Comment: @Suvitruf, ээх.

Answer (score 0):

Сарказмы или что там ещё вот это негативное, зачем писать вообще? Если копнуть глубже, то человек, считающий своим долгом "кольнуть" или "турнуть" кого-то за не совсем или совсем некорректный вопрос/ответ/комментарий, он что проявляет таким образом? Собственнический инстинкт? Собственное превосходство? Вроде бы, не нравится - дай конструктив или проходи мимо молча. А так - это что-то из разряда "О Господи, ещё один бездарь со своими глупостями на мою голову, однако я должен ответить, ибо кто же кроме меня".

Я полагаю, что документ очень полезен для самоконтроля и рефлексии всем пользователям. Повод лишний раз перечитать написанное перед отправкой.

Comment: Вы когда шутки рассказываете или с друзьями прикалываетесь, тоже делаете это из желания "кольнуть"? Некоторые расценивали SOru как уютненькое сообщество, где можно иногда безобидно подтрунивать над своими. Оказалось, что это у нас, всё же, не такая дружественная атмосфера.

Comment: @Suvitruf ключевое слово - «своими». Над «своими» подшучивайте сколько угодно. Нелепая аргументация

Comment: Нелепо требовать стерильности в общении.

Comment: @Suvitruf никакой речи о стерильности и не идёт. Есть чатики, где как раз-таки все «свои», чем не место проявить остроумие?

Answer (score -2):

Полностью - это нереально. НО, данная *рекомендация* мне скорее нравится. (вопрос о карах не затрагиваю, ибо они очень расплывчаты, да и сам документ еще не в своей финальной форме)

"В каждой шутке, есть доля шутки", не так ли? Как я ни люблю сарказм и иронию, но должен напомнить всем (и себе), что получать их в свой адрес не всегда приятно. За ними легко спрятать нападки и завуалировать оскорбления.

С возрастом и опытом, многие забывают о простых вещах, которые у них вызывали трудности в начале пути, и начинают язвить "Ну как так можно не знать что такое АБС, вас совсем не учат в БСД чтоли?". Хорошо ли это? Представьте себя в новой сфере деятельности (откройте случайный сайт SE) и попробуйте спросить что такое СДЕ на нем (а там, каждый третий - спец по СДЕ). Будет ли вам приятно получить порцию сарказма в ответ о том, в чем вы даже не разбираетесь, не владеете терминологией и не умеете формулировать мысль не кажущуюся бредом спецу? Вряд ли. Так что верно указано, не можете ответить "по теме" - пройдите мимо, а не тешьте свое ЧСВ.

Мне лично, данное правило (если оно станет правилом) будет скорее неприятно, но все же я вижу в нем больше пользы как для SO и ruSO, так и для себя, чем вреда. Общее искоренение форумности в пользу википедиезации скорее плюс, для Базы Знаний.

P.S. "Теплая ламповость" форумов меня никогда не прельщала, и я очень рад тому, что SO пришел им на смену в качестве Базы Знаний. Я пришёл на ruSO с enSO и на ХэшКоде никогда не был.

Comment: Штука в том, что не все воспринимают этот ресурс как базу знаний (я тому пример).

Comment: @ixSci расскажите, как вы воспринимаете? (хотя бы в каменте)

Comment: Для меня это в чём-то эволюционировавший, в чём-то деградировавший, но всё же форум. Важным аспектом форума является возможность общения, здесь она деградировала. Но недостатком форума является сложность выявления полезных сообщений, здесь это эволюционировало. Более того, мне кажется, что мало кто вообще воспринимает этот ресурс как базу знаний. Даже термин БЗ это калька, которую в русском языке не часто встретишь. А вот те knowledge base, которые мне известны, не похожи на SE (MS KB и прочие).

Comment: KB это фактически набор рецептов, мне претит подобное стремление. Рецептами людей ничему не научишь.

Comment: Вы верно заметили про то что одно лечим, а другое калечим! БЗ в KB плохи тем, что они пишутся "сверху", а SO же силен тем, что в нем БЗ строится "снизу". Итого я бы не синонимизировал KB с БЗ - это разные вещи.

Comment: @ixSci сейчас jfs придёт и объяснит по понятиям :D Я, если что, SO никогда не считал и не буду считать просто БЗ.

Comment: Хотя вы во многом правы, но сама мысль о том, что шуточки (пусть даже не слишком удачные) кто-то будет выпиливать сообразно своему вкусу, отвращает меня (наверное, не одного) от желания передавать свои знания людям, которые согласны с таким ограничением свободы.

Comment: @avp напомню, что все ответы на SO свободно редактируемы и все шуточки могут выпиливаться и так. Тем не менее, этим никто особо не злоупотребляет, а ответы - в большинстве своем, и так лишены "шуточек".

Comment: Могут. Но стоит закрепить новые правила и десяток упертых кинется искать и выпиливать-флагать все напоминающее иронию-сарказм-юмор и т.д. Как известно -- "заставь дурака Богу молиться, он лоб расшибет".

Comment: @avp не совсем понимаю связь между "стоит закрепить" и "заставь молиться". Звучит как необоснованные опасения. К примеру, достаточно давно решили, что лишние приветствия не нужны, или что писать надо грамотно, или код и цитаты форматировать - и всё равно вроде как нет никаких толп ищущих "приветы" или опчеатки и массово их исправляющих.

Comment: И что, приветы не выпиливают? Серьезно? Зайдите в чат и спросите там

Comment: @avp вы написали - *"и десяток упертых кинется искать и выпиливать"* Поиск по слову "привет" на ruSO дает овер 9к результатов (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?page=7&tab=Relevance&q=Привет), из которых приветствием является около 90%. Что-то не похоже, чтобы их кто-то ***искал*** или ***массово выпиливал***.

Comment: Значит обеспокоенность кого-то в чате была ложной тревогой. Но, в любом случае мне не нравится тенденция к росту прописанных в правилах ограничений. Чем-то напоминает всю бодягу с *оскорблением чувств верующих* в нашем законодательстве (со всеми вытекающими...)

Comment: @avp я бы тоже поставил вопрос к КМ и модераторам насчет статуса CoC в целом, будет ли он сводом правил, или рекоммендаций, или как-то еще. А то сейчас это какая-то серая территория. То есть я поддерживаю, что "нельзя бросать фантики мимо урны", но при адекватном ответе (поправить или предупредить), а не как тут все боятся "баном".

Answer (score -4):

Не могу не процитировать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы уверены, что это ответ, а не комментарий? Мне кажется это не тянет на полноценный ответ, а является комментарием-"чисто поржать". Попробуете развернуть свою мысль и оставить картинку иллюстрацией к ней?

Comment: @Kromster абсолютно. К сожалению, если я начну давать развёрнутые ответы на посты с обсуждениями бинайсных правил ресурса, то не удержусь и просто заменю эту весёлую картинку на скриншот публичного националистического высказывания одного из соучредителей Stackoverflow. Этот веский аргумент сведёт к нулю все старания администрации и нанесёт ресурсу больше урона, чем пользы.

Comment: Развернутый ответ, вовсе не означает необходимости переходить на личности или переходить к обмену цитатами. Право ваше. Просто высказанное мнение несет больше веса, чем не высказанное, или голая "веселая картинка с Реддита/Пикабу/Вк/итп".

Comment: @Kromster развёрнутый ответ требует аргументации, а не может быть более веского аргумента, чем доказательство лицемерия.

Comment: Эмм... Ну так и напишите хотя бы, что против полного запрета ввиду того, что иронию/сарказм используют все, в том числе мод.состав и вам не представляется реалистичным, что они так же будут следовать такому запрету (когда/если он будет принят). Если я вас правильно понял. *Напоминаю, что закон обратной силы, обычно, не имеет.*

Comment: @Kromster а я не против. Это их ресурс, им решать какие правила на нём будут действовать.

Comment: ну как бы да, ресурс, вообще-то, коммерческий, чего вообще все так распереживались из-за этих игрищ в демократию?

Comment: @Anatol я ни капельки не переживаю. Просто ценю последовательность.