# Использование инструментов модератора в чатах смежных подсайтов сети SE и механизмы опротестования

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, модерация, чат, инструменты-модератора

Начну с конца - действий, которые стали последней каплей. Сегодня в чате я пытался выяснить, где граница, после которой слова воспринимаются как оскорбление.

В процессе обсуждения был получен бан за упоминание ссылки на *говнокод.ру*.

[image: история удалённого сообщения]

Мне кажется, что люди с других сайтов подсети и не знакомые со спецификой других областей не должны вмешиваться в дела этих сайтов.

Решил пока здесь задать вопрос.

1. Что делать, если в работу одного сайта вмешивается модератор другого сайта сети SE, не знакомый с областью сайта?
2. Можно ли как-то ограничить возможности модераторов других сайтов?

Если этот вопрос не в рамках рассмотрения локальных сообществ, следует ли мне задать этот вопрос на MSE?

P.S. К сожалению, я не смог задать вопрос, не упоминая конкретных участников.

Comment: Пожалуйта, не искажайте факты. Например, гифка с собачкой была отправлена в ответ на сообщение с отказом формулировать аргументы, автором которого является другой участник.

Comment: @Aer гифка показывает вашу несерьёзность. К слову, вопросы про бан вы проигнорировали вовсе.

Comment: Несерьезность? Считайте как хотите, но моей целью было лишь донести свое недоумение с помощью хорошо его выражающей гифки. Последовательно употребляя вульгарные слова и игнорируя все предупреждения, вы провоцировали других участников и нарушали [нормы поведения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct). Пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с ними и обратите особое внимание на пункт «Никакой нетерпимости».

Comment: @Aer заметьте, при любой попытке пойти с вами на диалог вы отнекиваетесь "считайте как хотите". Странно такое слышать от модератора. Поучились бы у того же PashaPash, например. Если вы не хотите вступать в диалог и объяснять свои действия, то не используйте инструменты модератора - это не игрушка.

Comment: Я всегда готов к конструктивному уважительному диалогу и я отвечал на ваши вопросы в чате ранее. Готов и сейчас. Пойдемте в чате, если вам что-то непонятно или вы хотите о чем-то спросить. «Считайте как хотите» значит, что вы вольны иметь любое мнение обо мне или любом другом человеке и я не буду его оспаривать.

Answer (score 11):

Сама по себе эта техническая реализация очень странная. Могу предположить, что разработчики не стали реализовывать привязку ромбов к сайтам потому что модератор - лицо, которому компания доверяет, которое связано юридическим агриментом. Не предполагается, что модератор может намеренно усугублять атмосферу в сообществе.

Всегда ли это работает? Абсолютно точно — нет!
Модератор должен отдавать себе отчёт в границах своих реальных(не технических) полномочий.
Сеть SE очень обширна, как обширен и он-топик в ней.
Представьте себе модератора канала культуры, который обосновался в чате у сообщества антропологов/медиков и раздаёт баны за каждое упоминание неполиткорректной расы или полового органа - и вы получите проблему, ситуацию, подобную нашей.

Борьба с ветряными мельницами за чистоту языка в сообществе программистов, такими как безобидные «говнокод» или тот же обратный отсчёт «5 4 3 2 1» абсолютно не стоит того филанизия, которое получает сообщество после подобных блокировок. Любая блокировка должна быть взвешена, сопоставлен нанесённый участником урон с уроном самой блокировки участнику и сообществу.

Основная проблема видимо в том, что технических возможностей повлиять на это поведение практически нет - только сложная процедура снятия ромба.
Причём в нашем случае, вполне вероятно, что за снятием ромба может последовать ликвидация сообщества «Русский язык», чего не хотелось бы ни при каких раскладах.
Самым реальным выходом из этой ситуации видится разговор с конкретным модератором с целью объяснить/убедить его воздержаться от модерирования чата чужого сообщества.

Я убеждён, что указанный модератор способен найти в себе достаточно благоразумия, чтобы отказаться от идеи, что он, как модератор, обязан реагировать на подобные вещи, и усилием воли перестать пользоваться своими полномочиями в целях наведения порядка в чате сообщества ruSO.

Comment: “только сложная процедура снятия ромба” Что в ней сложного? И причём тут вообще ликвидация РЯ? Там пока что еще пара модераторов.

Comment: Сложная процедура снятия ромба, ха-ха.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, о, привет! =) Насколько я понимаю, процедура вообще не предусмотрена, но всё в этом мире реализуемо, например, можно раздуть скандал в соцсетях, обвинить в нетолерастии и т.п.; В общем, сложная процедура.

Comment: @vp_arth была предусмотрена и раньше, теперь стала ещё более четкой и документированной. А Монику уволили в обход процедуры, про то и сарказм.

Comment: А, у вас тут новые драмы) А я всё пропустил.

Answer (score 3):

#### Может ли модератор одного сообщества блокировать участников за нарушение в основном чате другого сообщества?

**Да, может.**

Хотя у каждого сообщества есть основной чат, система чатов едина для всей платформы. Модератор любого сайта может удалить не соответствующие правилам этого сайта сообщения, если того требует ситуация.

На мой взгляд, очень важно понимать, что большинство правил и принципов проекта едины для всех сообществ сети Stack Exchange. Например, те же нормы поведения едины. И если участник (модератор) справляется с модерацией чата своего сообщества, нет причин полагать, что что–то может пойти не так  в чате другого сообщества. К тому же, большинство из модераторов заняты своим сообществом, а в другое заходят в исключительных ситуациях, например, по сигналу тревоги.

#### Что делать, если в работу одного сайта вмешивается модератор другого сайта сети SE, не знакомый с областью сайта?

Быть вежливым, подразумевать добрые намерения и, в случае неоднозначных ситуаций, быть готовым пояснить контекст происходящего максимально подробно, чтобы избежать возможных недоразумений.

#### ...область сайта

Как вы верно заметили, заходя в сообщество лингвистов, вы рискуете наткнуться на [рассмотрение](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/2987/5402) весьма неоднозначных терминов. Заходя в сообщество по анатомии, вы можете столкнуться с анатомическими подробностями жизнедеятельности человека, что вполне ожидаемо.

Так вот, когда кто–то заходит в чат по программированию, он ожидает увидеть в нем портянки кода, но никак не названия переработанной организмом человека пищи, политику или аналогичные приведенным выше лингвистические дебаты. Для сообщества программистов это не является нормой и область сайта об этом явно говорит. Если вы были неверно поняты и предполагаете, что дело в «непонимании области сайта», есть высокая вероятность, что это не только проблема читающего.

#### Можно ли как-то ограничить возможности модераторов других сайтов?

На данный момент — нет. Это правило едино для всех сайтов сети. Возможности вносить исключения нет. Участник либо может быть модератором и помогать соблюдать правила сети в любом чате, либо не может.

#### Если этот вопрос не в рамках рассмотрения локальных сообществ, следует ли мне задать этот вопрос на MSE?

Если вы хотите внести изменения в то, как работает движок, вам следует вынести ваше предложение на MSE с соответствующей меткой.

Comment: О каком диалоге речь, когда за вопрос о причине бана я получил новый бан?

Comment: @Suvitruf Большое спасибо за вопрос! Возможно, что–то пошло не так. Приношу свои извинения от лица команды модерации за возможно неверное действие. Мы открыли дискуссию на эту тему в команде модерации и с модераторами всей сети Stack Exchange в общем.

Comment: Извинения то, конечно, приняты, хотя я и не просил извиняться. Моё единственное желание - предотвратить/оградить участников от такого в будущем.

Comment: @Suvitruf "за вопрос о причине бана я получил новый бан" - модератор овладел рекурсией? Налицо польза (для модератора) от модерирования ruSO!

Comment: @Igor ещё пару лет и сможет написать `Hello World` :D

Answer (score 2):

Я бы хотел в своём ответе затронуть несколько аспектов поднятого вопроса.

Поехали по порядку.

#### Является ли слово "г..нокод" оскорбительным?

Русский язык -- весьма выразительный и глубокий язык, который позволяет говорящему выразить свою мысль множеством различных способов. Никто не отрицает, что существует такое явление, как "плохой" код -- но существует весьма большое число способов выразить свою мысль, в том числе -- не используя туалетный юмор, не прибегая к оценочным суждениям и тому подобным вещам.

В английской литературе (а английский -- де-факто стандартный язык отрасли) принят термин 'code smells' (тут такие умные отсылки к книгам Фаулера и других отцов).

Не буду глубоко вдаваться в анализ английского термина, но насколько я знаю smell - это и 'пахнуть' как аромат парфюма (odor, aroma) так и 'вонять' (stinky).

Устоявшимся термином в русском языке являются термины "запах кода" и "код с запашком", глагольные формы - "этот код попахивает". Сомневающихся отправляю к академическим изданиям книг и в википедию, которая фиксирует именно т.н. авторитетные источники.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Свобода выбора слов и терминов -- за вами ([пример](http://macode.ru/), [исходник](http://programming-motherfucker.com/)), просто надо иметь ввиду, что в приличных домах принято выражаться на приличном языке. Сложно возмущаться в ресторане, что вы привыкли класть ноги на стол -- и апеллировать "вот в моей любимой забегаловке за углом всегда так разрешают". Тут надо всё-таки сообразить, что некоторые вещи плохо сочетаются друг с другом (условно -- белые скатерти и сонные официантки), а с недавних пор на дверях именно этого заведения ещё более крупным шрифтом написано, что заведение стало причислять себя к категории "пять звёзд". Вот тут: [Conduct](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/conduct)

#### Уместно ли жестить на кодревью и в ответах на stackoverflow?

Я хотел бы [перенести в ответ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46252528#46252528) часть про "ревьюеров второго сорта". В чате речь зашла о том, что используя <s>калёное железо</s> резкие формулировки без "сюсюканья" кодревью становится более эффективным.

> «Иногда, читая чужой код видишь настолько несовершенные конструкции,
>   что приходится прибегать к ненормативной лексике» =)
>
> Чувства я уважаю за кружкой пива в баре. А косяки в коде показываю
>   прямо, без увиливаний. И поржать могу. И коллегам нравится моя
>   нелицеприятность и объективность в этом плане. Сами код на посмотреть
>   несут. Потому что они так быстрее учатся, растут, чем с сюсюканьем.

Я читал много книг и статей по методикам рефакторинга и проведения ревью кода и в них стандартным местом идёт что-то в духе "уважайте чувства тех, чей код вы комментируете. Обсуждайте действия, а не человека".

У меня сложилось мнение, что есть ревьюеры второго сорта (низшие сорта не рассматриваем), когда человек по делу распекает матюгами плохой код. От этого новички растут быстро и хорошо, но есть некоторый процент брака в виде сорванной резьбы. Я имею ввиду конфликты в команде, которые часто заканчиваются увольнением, прошу прощения за эдакий эвфемизм.

И есть ещё ревьюеры -- первосортные, которые умеют учить уважая людей. Увы, их много меньше, но это именно тот идеал специалиста, за которым гоняются охотники за головами.

Я вижу на сайте много хороших специалистов, даже третьесортные отвечающие у нас быстро растут: отвечают на вопросы и тем самым прокачивают свои скилы.

Правда я почему-то не видел ещё ни одного случая, когда бы второсортный ревьюер сказал бы себе "эгей, я буду не просто отвечать на вопросы -- но буду при этом прокачивать навык уважительного ревью" (и на том бы выросли).

И почему-то я постоянно встречаю паттерн "как хочу отвечать на вопросы, так и буду: я хочу привести людей быстро к знанию, поэтому терпи, Петька, все твои косяки покажу прямо, без увиливаний, да ещё и шуточками присыплю, чтобы тебе было не так больно". (К слову: именно отсюда во многом [растёт тревога](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7593/213987) "нам запретят иронию")

Ну да, "нам этот первоклассное ревью не заплатят", так в общем-то и ответы дело добровольное. Каждый для себя сам решает, где и сколько он бесплатного даст сообществу, а где пойдёт на сайты, где за ответы денежку заплатят. (Вечно теряю эту ссылку Николаса, ага, вот: https://www.experts-exchange.com/)

Я [как-то писал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7637/213987): если вы испытываете злость и раздражение от того, что другие ведут себя не так как вы ожидали -- попробуйте понять, что сила эмоций прямо пропорциональна дельте ожидаемого (то, что вы себе придумали) и реально полученного. Чем более прекрасную и возвышенную цель вы себе поставите ("база знаний" там или "я приведу людей к знанию") тем больше будет людей, которые не пройдут под ваши лекала - начиная от "домашки", "лентяев", "не даю ответы тем, кто пишет мне 'эй, быра'", "вам на работе платят за этот код, поэтому думайте сами" и так далее. Да, это всё -- очень плохие вещи, но я думаю в жизни есть более хорошие цели, чем борьба с домашкой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Просто оставьте отвечать на домашку тем, кто считает это морально приемлемым, а сами займитесь ответом на те вопросы, которые лично вам нравятся. Вообще, это хороший принцип сохранения душевного спокойствия: делать то, что нравится.

#### Что вообще происходит в чате?

О происходящем в чате в целом. Моё личное суждение, взглядом человека, который старается не сильно погружаться в эту свару, но наблюдает её изнутри уже несколько месяцев.

Видели когда-нибудь, как дети пробуют границы мира? А вот так можно? А вот так? А если я ещё чуть-чуть поднажму? Происходящее мне очень сильно напоминает мне такую игру, в которую с увлечением играют некоторые участники сообщества.

Они действительно хотят понимать, где проходит граница новых правил и тестируют и экспериментируют. А вот это слово можно? А вот такое?

Игра увлекательная (доберётесь до хотя бы 10к+ репутации -- возможно и вам надоест отвечать на однообразные вопросы), групповая (когда тебя поддерживает другой как-то не так страшно и чувствуешь это великое "мы"), опасная (кому не хочется показаться сильным и ловким?).

Когда кто-то наконец-то ловит "банан", то оказывается, что со стороны администрации это расценивается как "травля модераторов", а в русском бюрократическом есть такой замечательный оборот как "в составе организованной ('кукловодом') группы лиц по предварительному ('альтчат') сговору".

Ну у меня какие новости. (Не могу расценить как новость "начальник всегда прав": уже пять раз за время конфликта [обсуждали это](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7226/213987) "смиритесь")

Во-первых, я вижу что до травли администрации уже практически рукой подать -- даже по-моим достаточно взвешенным оценкам.

Во-вторых, почему никто не хочет понять, что на этом сайте практически нет "администрации", тут лишь один КМ на окладе. По ту сторону конфликта -- те же самые "мы", точно такие же добровольные участники. PashaPash вышел из народа, Aer точно такой же участник, как и мы с вами. Когда кто-то говорит "я не подписывался на сайте делать то-то" -- это по-вашему нормально, а когда вы тут же хотите повесить кучу обязанностей на модератора и указываете, как нужно правильно вести -- это по-вашему выглядит достойно? Мне кажется было бы полезно перед тем как просить что-то PashaPash или Aer вида "вы обязаны" -- попробуйте представить, что это вы сами будете завтра на месте этого человека и к вам кто-то придёт с такими речами.

Может быть уже пора остановиться, а?

#### Можно ли не пускать на сайт/чат модераторов с других сайтов сети SE?

В текущей ситуации - нельзя, об этом смотри ответ Николаса.

Насчёт того, что с этим делать.

В самом вопросе есть некоторая сумятица мыслей. С одной стороны тут и утверждение "это слово вполне нормальное" (я посвятил часть своего ответа анализу этого слова -- и немного упомянул правила конкретно этого сайта), с другой стороны это и вытекающее из утверждения "модератор был неправ" (повторю ещё раз ссылку: [Какие предусмотрены пути опротестования решения администрации?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7226/213987) и добавлю, что мне лично вообще не очень понятно, где решать конфликт: на местном сайте в форме обратной связи или на его мете, на том, сайте откуда модератор, на метасайте)

Вероятно, тут мы приходим к большому вопросу, а не стоит ли на метамету вынести вопрос о том, чтобы модераторы были ограничены рамками своих сайтов и не ходили в другие сообщества. Механизмов для этого нет (судя по ответу Николаса, это так не задумывалось бай дизайн -- и предполагались исключительно добрые намерения), поэтому на мой взгляд нужно идти именно туда и там решать вопрос.

Потому что решая исключительно вопрос с каким-то одним модератором -- мы рискуем придти к повторению ситуации с другим модератором. В рамках всей сети кажется, что это происходит нечасто, но когда вы сидите только на одном -- вам может показаться, что постоянно приходят какие-то посторонние люди, не имеющие отношения к вашему сайту, а это может очень сильно раздражать и цифры "в целом по сети это очень редко происходить" вас не утешат.

Comment: И вроде красивый текст, но с другой стороны, но совсем понимаю, как он с вопросом вяжется, если честно =/

Comment: @Suvitruf Прекрасно вяжется. Вы смешали в одном вопросе несколько аспектов и я на них последовательно отвечал. Например, "плохое ли слово г-код" - я дал краткий анализ с отсылками к Фаулеру. Этот вопрос является ключом к вопросу "модератор перегнул палку или нет", лично я ближе к "нет". Ещё одна часть вопроса как заметил ПП является проблемой смешения подсайтов -- но уж извините, когда на вопрос повесили лок я решил пока не трепыхаться, раз мой ответ пойдёт под нож и будет два других вопроса.

Comment: Было бы здорово добавить немного подзаголовков в столь длинный ответ, чтобы он не сливался в единую wall-of-text

Comment: @Kromster Спасибо за обратную связь, поправил.

Comment: @AK Прекрасный текст, очень жаль, что он так "заминусован". Возможно, очень у нас в сообществе много любителей троллить (хотя они, скорей всего, думают, что это нормальные шуточки).

Comment: Я не понимаю, каким образом фраза *"Чем более прекрасную и возвышенную цель вы себе поставите ("база знаний" там или "я приведу людей к знанию") тем больше будет людей, которые не пройдут под ваши лекала"* оправдывает творящейся в чате произвол конкретного модератора. В моей картине мира именно он поставил перед собой слишком возвышенную цель, к которой не подходит большая часть участников...

Comment: Да, и "код с запахом" - ни разу не синоним "говнокоду". Запах в коде - это единичная странность, обсуждаемое же слово означает код, в котором неправильно очень многое.

Answer (score -5):

Вопрос был радикально изменен, и теперь ответ требуется, видимо, на его последнюю редакцию.

Ваше сообщение, содержащее термин «говнокод», было удалено с учетом контекста. До него вами были опубликованы сообщения, содержащие обвинения в гомофобстве, слово «херня», заметив которые, я попросил вас не переходить на личности и не использовать вульгарную лексику. Три моих предупреждения были прогинорированы, поэтому проблемное поведение было пресечено, а сообщения, содержащие бранные слова, удалены.

### Об удаленном вопросе

Слово «говнокод», хоть и является жаргонизмом, все равно содержит вульгарный корень *говн-*, использование которого крайне нежелательно в уважительной беседе. Вы задали вопрос, который был удален, так как контекст беседы рождал ощущение, что ваша цель — провокация модераторов (косвенное подтверждение этому содержится в констатации вами же вашего желания проверить, насколько Aer чувствительный). Приношу свои извинения, если ваши намерения были чисты и вы вовсе не хотели кого-либо спровоцировать, проверить на крепкость и т. п. Надеюсь, что после произошедшего мы сможем находить ответы на вопросы о правомерности использовании тех или иных слов более миролюбивым путем.

### О возможности использовать слово «говнокод»

Как было замечено выше, несмотря на то, что слово «говнокод» довольно распространено и используется как термин среди некоторых программистов, его упоминание на сайтах сети Stack Exchange крайне нежелательно. Вот лишь некоторые контексты, в которых оно может быть не признано нарушением действующих [норм поведения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct):

- Можно ли использовать на сайте слово «говнокод»?
- Почему «говнокод» — это грубо?

### Об использовании грубых слов в ссылках

Каким бы хорошим или нормальным ни был сайт, если в своем названии он содержит слово, неуместное в уважительной беседе, нарушающее наши правила, давать на него ссылки не стоит. Уверен, что, если возникнет отстрая необходимость в том, чтобы поделиться какой-либо вульгарной, интимной и прочей не уместной на сайтах сети Stack Exchange информацией с другими участниками, это всегда можно сделать, используя подходящие сервисы.

---

Еще раз повторю, что мне жаль, если обсуждаемое удаление кажется вам неправомерным. Команда модераторов (к которой принадлежу и я) внимательно рассмотрела происшедшее и сделала необходимые выводы, чтобы сократить число ошибок в будущем.

Надеюсь, мой ответ окажется полезным!

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81820/discussion-on-answer-by-aer------).