# Оскорбление или нет, вот в чём вопрос

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, чат, инструменты-модератора

Связанный вопрос, чтоб понять откуда ноги растут:

[Использование инструментов модератора в чатах смежных подсайтов сети SE и механизмы опротестования](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7683/15479)

Некоторые увидели в довольно широкоиспользуемом термине оскорбление, хотя очевидно, что фраза вообще не была направлена ни на конкретных участников, ни на конкретный вопрос/ответ.

1. Для начала стоит сказать, что я не приветствую глумление или издевательства над другими разработчиками, какой бы плохой код они ни писали, а то почему-то во время обсуждения некоторые посчитали, что раз ты называешь код ****, то ты считаешь человека ****.
2. Если негативно отзываются о коде, это не значит, что негативно относятся к человеку.
3. **Речь сейчас именно про чат**, где царит неформальная обстановка.

А теперь по существу. Есть довольно очевидные термины/слова, которые в большинстве случаев используются для оскорбления. Вопрос не про них. Вопрос про слова, которые повседневно используются в речи.

Есть пара моментов:

1. Такие слова используются как гипербола, чтобы донести до собеседника значительность, поставить акцент. Не нужно говорить, что "можно найти аналог".
2. Слова, которые довольно давно уже устоялись в кругу разработчиков. Они могут быть слегка вульгарными, не более.
3. По поводу слова из сабжа, в английском есть шуточная форма подобного - monkey's code. Такие слова могут использоваться для оскорбления, а могут и нет. Банить/удалять, как это было с сабжем, неверно, т.к. не учтён контекст.

А теперь вопросы:

1. Кто решает, какие слова запрещено произносить? До недавних пор подобные слова мелькали в чате, и никто не обижался. Что поменялось? Разве это должны решать не те, кто общаются в чате? Тревог от пользователей не было, так с чего вдруг тогда используется инструмент модератора?
2. Что делать человеку, который не согласен с удалением/баном? Если он обратится к модераторам, то они будут не на его стороне. Если человек не знает английского, то обратиться к руководству не может в принципе.
3. Что делать, когда оскорбления и клевета поступают от модераторов? Тревоги на сообщениях модераторов ни к чему не приводят, т.к. приходят модераторы с иностранных сайтов, не понимающие контекста, и просто ничего не делают.

Comment: Похоже, что если вам нужна неформальная обстановка в чате - теперь вам нужен другой чат.

Comment: @vp_arth неформальная - не означает, что все могут друг друга оскорблять. Это означает, что имеют место быть небольшие шутки и т.п.

Comment: @Drakonoved: А что толку подстраиваться под малоадекватных людей, которые не могут отличить критику кода от оскорбления личности? Если под каждого подстраиваться, придётся подстраиваться и под тех, кто считает упоминание шарообразной Земли оскорблением.

Comment: @Drakonoved Влад считает, что неженок меньшинство. Вы считаете, что большинство )

Comment: Как всё запутанно (:

Answer (score 17):

Поскольку администрация не высказывается, я выскажу своё мнение, у меня как раз свободные 30 минут нарисовались.

Итак, в хорошем, правильном сообществе должен быть самоочевидный консенсус о том, что разрешено, а что запрещено произносить. В случае необходимости консенсус может закрепляться голосованием участников (в нашем случае для этого вполне пригодна Мета). Если кто-либо не согласен с текущим консенсусом, он не должен односторонне навязывать сообществу правила, мы это ненавидим. Единственный верный путь — **убедить** сообщество поменять свой консенсус. (И подчиниться мнению сообщества, если сообщество не будет убеждено аргументацией.)

(И да, простое упоминание баззвордов наподобие «это расистское слово» или «не обидеть котяток» не считается аргументом: если какое-то слово **реально** обидно для нас, вам должно быть легко убедить в этом сообщество.)

В хорошем, правильном сообществе должна быть возможность оспорить бан. Для этого должно быть возможно открыть тему (в нашем случае — на Мете) и обсудить действия модераторов. Модераторы должны быть готовы к публичному и нелицеприятному обсуждению своих действий, на то они и публичные фигуры.
(Да, роль модератора не должна сводиться к раздаче банов, модераторы должны быть ответственны перед сообществом, выбравшим их, за свои действия.)

С другой стороны, если сообщество согласно с баном, то участник, отвлекающий сообщество требованиями смягчения, должен исходить из возможности дальнейшего ужесточения наказания сообществом. Сообщество не любит тех, кто злоупотребляет его ресурсами.

В хорошем, правильном сообществе модератор — слуга сообщества, а не наоборот. Оскорбления, поступающие от модератора, должны рассматриваться сообществом, и если сообщество найдёт действия модератора ошибочными, оно должно принять решение: от милосердного предупреждения, до снятия модераторского ромба, в крайних случаях — до изгнания из сообщества.

Сообщество должно иметь возможность само оценивать то, насколько хорошо модератор ему служит.

Модераторы других сообществ, не выбранные нашим сообществом и не подотчётные ему, вовсе не должны быть допущены к модерированию нашего сообщества. (Ведь глава министерства не может управлять сотрудниками другого министерства лишь на том основании, что он глава *какого-то* министерства?)

---

А как оно у нас, пускай скажет администрация или модсостав.

Comment: Про Зимбабве не очень сравнение. Ближе была бы аналогия: глава республики/штата не может наводить порядки в другой республике/штате.

Comment: @Suvitruf Про штаты не очень сравнение. Ближе была бы аналогия: судья республики  Татарстан может осудить жителя Новосибирска.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan *если бы судья Татарстана, находясь в Новосибирске, судил бы жителей Новосибирска.

Comment: @Suvitruf: Я не очень разбираюсь в юридических тонкостях, поэтому взял самый выпуклый пример. Сейчас поменяю.

Comment: @Suvitruf У судей на всей территории РФ единый статус (з.N3132-1пп2.1), не вижу проблем. Примерно как и у модераторов в отношении чатов =)

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan интересно. Всегда думал, что у них региональные полномочия.

Comment: @Suvitruf Как бы там ни было, вариант с министерством от ВладДа довольно удачный.

Answer (score 1):

Я постарался раскрыть вопрос модерации чатов подробно в «[Модерация чатов Сети](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7827/6)». Посмотрите, пожалуйста. В нем есть ответы на большинство указанных вами вопросов.

Несколько коротких комментариев, которые не раскрыты в указанном выше вопросе по модерированию:

> какие слова запрещено произносить?

Когда я делал [модератор комментариев](http://benice.rudevs.ru/), мне нужен был [словарь «плохих» слов](https://github.com/chabanovsky/so-comment-moderator/blob/master/wiktionary_org.py) для обучения модели.

1. Я нашел очень полезным сайт wiktionary.org. В нем есть несколько интересных нам разделов:

   - [Матерные выражения](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/ru).
   - [Бранные выражения](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/ru).
   - [Грубые выражения](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%93%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/ru).
   - [Ироничные выражения](https://ru.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%98%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/ru)
   - [Презрительные выражения](https://ru.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/ru)
   - [Пренебрежительные выражения](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/ru)
   - [Уничижительные выражения](https://ru.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A3%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/ru)
2. Так же я составил [свой словарь](https://github.com/chabanovsky/so-comment-moderator/blob/master/db_models.py#L39) по комментариям, которые были отмечены как оскорбительные и [доп. словарь стоп слов](https://github.com/chabanovsky/so-comment-moderator/blob/master/db_models.py#L40). Как можно увидеть, в нем есть такие слова как «женщина», «наркоман», «петух». Их невозможно отнести к оскорблениям самих по себе, но они редко встречаются на сайте в своем изначальном значении.

Вывод: определить набор слов, который «запрещен» довольно сложно. Для многих слов важен контекст. Но! Есть общепринятая ненормативная лексика. Ее употреблять не стоит точно. Эти слова являются оскорбительными и без контекста (список выше). То, что они оскорбительные решил не один модератор, а все Вики–сообщество. Если считаете, что в списке есть ошибочно классифицированные слова, обязательно отпишитесь об этом на wiktionary.org!

> Разве это должны решать не те, кто общаются в чате? Тревог от пользователей не было, так с чего вдруг тогда используется инструмент модератора?

Подробно ответил в «[Модерация чатов Сети](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7827/6)». Кратко:

- Модерация происходит на нескольких уровнях. Если проблему не нашли / не видят на одном уровне, это не означает, что ее нет.
- Чаты полностью публичны и модерируются всеми участниками. Следствие: любой участник с необходимыми привилегиями может принять участие в решении по контенту, в том числе модератор любого сообщества Stack Exchange. Таков механизм работы наших чатов.

> Что делать человеку, который не согласен с удалением/баном?

- Задать вопрос на Мете, учитывая «[Следует ли обращаться к участникам по имени в вопросах на Мете?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4790/6)».
- Написать модераторам (можно попросить создать закрытый чат для более приватной дискусси).
- Написать в поддержку через [форму обратной связи](/contact).

> Что делать, когда оскорбления и клевета поступают от модераторов?

Аналогично выше описанному.

---

На мой взгляд, самое важное, что упускается из виду:

1. Помните, что нас всех объединяет стремление к знаниям.
2. Подразумевайте добрые намерения коллег.

Если вы видите, что что–то пошло не так, пожалуйста, вернитесь к основной теме сайта, к которому прикреплен чат, а вместо злости или обиды отвечайте добротой. Если что–то продолжительное время идет не так, напишите об этом на Мете, модераторам и через обратную связь. Вам обязательно помогут!

Comment: Пещерный человек, который не видел плохого в красивой и, возможно, доброй змее, прожил меньше того, кто сделал от неё ноги. Вот вам и "подразумевайте добрые намерения".

Comment: @Hades смысл метафоры ускользает от меня. Можете раскрыть его в контексте ответа? )

Comment: @Suvitruf, КМ говорит что во всём (что касается сайта) надо в первую очередь видеть хорошее и только при явных доказательствах обратного вежливо забанить. Обязательно вежливо! Я же так не думаю, поэтому и написал пример почему даже эволюционно выгоднее сначала как раз протестировать на плохое. Надежду на то, что будет хорошо - это всегда за, но не обратно.

Comment: Наблюдается какое-то [противоречие](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/4791/5) при ситуации с модераторами. Так использовать мету или нет?

Comment: @alexolut нет. Нужно накрыться пледом и плакать)