Опрос для пользователей: как вернуть активность на ru.SO?
Недавно на Мете обсуждалось значительное снижение активности на ru.SO, особенно с февраля 2023 года. Гипотезы включают влияние распространения ChatGPT и другие возможные факторы, такие как изменение поискового трафика и внутренние проблемы платформы. Затем в комментариях было обсуждение, где один участник предложил как можно узнать реальную причину оттока, другой мотивировал на создание вопроса, а я попробую поднять тему, а сообщество выскажет свое мнение и решит.

Возникло предложение: можем ли мы, а вернее модераторы, отправлять
email-рассылки зарегистрированным пользователям, чтобы собрать их
мнение о причинах снижения активности и предложениях по улучшению
сайта?

Возможный формат опроса:

Почему вы стали реже использовать ru.SO?
Какие у вас идеи для улучшения сайта?
итд...

Такая рассылка могла бы помочь не только активным участникам, но и привлечь внимание менее активных пользователей, а также дать полезную обратную связь для будущих улучшений.
Как вы считаете, стоит ли предпринимать такие шаги? Соответствует ли это политике сайта? Насколько эффективной, по вашему мнению, будет такая рассылка, и что ещё можно сделать для преодоления текущего спада на ru.SO?

upd
Пожалуйста, ответьте на следующие вопросы и оставьте комментарии, чтобы лучше прояснить картину:

Почему вы стали реже использовать ru.SO?
Какие факторы, на ваш взгляд, повлияли на снижение активности?
Какой формат привлечения пользователей был бы полезен?

Отвечайте на каждый пункт как отдельный ответ — это поможет сообществу выделить наиболее важные моменты через голосование.

что ещё можно сделать для преодоления текущего спада сделать наконец песочницу, причем опциональную(с возможностью подключить её к вопросу даже при высоком рейте, подобно меткам). щас ведь как - большая часть вопросов уже задана и чем дальше, тем выше требования к задаваемому вопросу(дубликаты запрещены и т.п.). это заставляет оглядываться на а вдруг такое уже спрашивали - надо прочесать всю метку со всеми вытекающими. ну а чтоб не превратилась в помойку без надзора за ней - автоочистка(всё что скажем месяц провалялось там не поднявшись выше нулевого рейта - под снос). ну как то так...

@puffleeck, по-моему, мы не сможем вносить такие "глобальные" изменения. Но идея имеет место быть, и если есть например 70 процентов опроса с таким к примеру предложением, то наверняка это передадут в головной офис... Хотя...

тут(на мете) кроме меток есть и какие-то... мега-метки чтоли. скажем статус-завершено выделена оранжевым. если такие метки доступны только для модераторов, то как раз ими можно бы наколхозить систему апов уровня вопроса(для уникальных и важных вопросов кмк в самый раз будет). если конечно такое доступно и на самом русо.

Все ссылки из поисковиков ведут на enSO. Видится мне, что в этом и есть ключевая проблема. А лично мне не хватает форумной состовляющей на портале, чаты и мета это не совсем то;))

@Dev18 да головному офису до фени, движок уже как тыщу лет устарел, а разрабы и не чешутся.

@Amgarak, есть доля истины. Но наша задача не головной офис и не en.SO, а узнать причину "почему нас покинули"... И стали меньше задавать/спрашивать.

@Dev18 как я уже написал выше, дело в поисковой выдачи. ruSO почему-то хуже индексируется поисковыми машинами и возможно это сделано специально

На момент моей регистрации кстати я изначально нашла ru.SO, и только потом открыла аккаунт en.SO,что было 7 лет назад. То есть запросы на русском выдавали ru.SO,а потом уже для меня открылся en.SO//так может есть работа seo, которая "спрятала" сайт, и поэтому сейчас мы видим в поисковике все реже, ресурс.//на другом вопросе есть ответ MSDN.WhiteKnight, с которым я согласна полностью, но все же не спросив не узнаешь...

@Dev18, а не хотите прямо из этой темы сделать опросник? Тут же, в виде ответов. А по почте можно послать URL сюда (не все же, ранее активные заинтересованные лица, заглядывают в Мету)

@avp, да, есть идея. Но вопрос кто отправит меил - модераторы не имеют полномочий, мы тем более...не нашла в политике сайта такой инфы

@avp,  я изменила вопрос, что скажете? Если у вас есть идеи, как его улучшить, можете отредактировать его, как считаете нужным

@Dev18, замечательно. Первый шаг к реальным действиям. Посмотрим,  готово ли сообщество (по крайней мере увидим, какому проценту пользователей SO вообще интересна его судьба)

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11456/Бан-за-объяснение-своего-минуса/11465#11465 - по прошествии трёх с половиной лет готов повторить почти слово в слово. Однако я ошибся, написав, что stackoverflow это [умирание] не грозит - как оказалось, грозит.

Для возвращения активности есть очевидное решение -- нужно раздавать больше банов активным участникам!

@NowhereMan, это из разряда "Чтобы повысить кол-во людей, которые лечатся в нашей клинике, надо начать колечить прохожих в подворотне за углом этой самой клиники"))

@Chaos_Sower, пока что видим повышение активности на мете )

@NowhereMan, потому что люди начали пользоваться моим советом из анекдота

Я бы написал ответ, но вот вам целая статья Athari про уход.

Уже 2 недели прошло, а откликнулись 7 человек (тут 8 ответов, но один  относится к первой редакции вопроса). Думаю, процент печально очевиден... (пропал интерес к жизни в этих местах)

@avp, На ответах, также стоят "голоса", те, кто согласился, но не писал свой. На сайте самом очень мало людей заходит(в регулярно порядке то есть) , а те, кто не заходят их мнение мы не узнаем, тк опрос остаётся только здесь.

@Dev18, на странице с вопросами есть ссылка на эту тему, кто хочет, тот узнает об опросе. Так или иначе, отметились здесь всего 17 человек. Похоже, что остальным посетителям  положение дел на сайте не интересно

Да любое сообщество проходит свой пик активности (а то и не доходит до него) и умирает. И, думаю, ничего тут не сделаешь. Все далее написанное относится только к моей тематике - C++, алгоритмы, математика. ChapGPT рушит ruSO не потому, что он такой крутой, а потому что ruSO в своем стремлении к, гм, дружелюбности к новичкам выродилось в "а ну, лохи, быстро сделали мне домашку! Что, не можете? ну вы и тупыыые". А ChatGPT на это, не обижаясь, ответит :) Далее, набрался критический вес, так сказать — и на многие вопросы уже идут в лучшем случае комментарии, а не ответы, а в худшем — закрытие

как дубликата (не знаю, что "в лучшем", а что "в худшем"). Отметил бы падение уровня профессионализма; на многие вопросы отвечать становится просто неинтересно. Что до конкретных вопросов, то 1 - не стал. Захожу ежедневно. Отвечать только не на что... 2 - я об этом уже написал. Добавлю еще, что пришло новое поколение :) 3 - ничего не спасет, да и вряд ли могло. Все рассуждения о рекламе, роли модераторов и т.п. - лично я в них не верю. "Все когда-то умирают! Пришло его время..." © К/ф "Уже вчера"

я стал меньше сюда заглядывать потому как ухудшилось качество вопросов. это как зайти в модный ресторан - а там пол зала детей.)

@eri, вторая часть вашей фразы замечательно передаёт то, что есть - истину. Дети вырастают и для них другие становятся детьми))) по сути это и есть ответ - смена поколения. И тут как раз остаются титаны, которые передают эстафету... А там, примут этот олимпийский огонь или затушат, всё зависит только от "модников" и их примера. Ваша фраза замечательная, так как в ней непроизвольно идёт истина. Качество вопросов ухудшилось для вас. Я часто смотрю старые вопросы и сегодня такое закрыли бы, но там стоят куча плюсиков. Хорошо, что вы на ru.SO

@eri Скорее ресторан тот же - детское кафе-мороженое, просто мы растем :)

Раз сюда меня так насильно тянули, что же, давайте выскажу свое мнение...
Комьюнити менеджер и RuSO на самоуправлении
Господа и дамы, вы ничего не сделаете от слова совсем! SO уже давно умирает, уже давно катится в пропасть, этому не помешать, да и не в наших силах что либо с этим делать. Почему? А все просто, ruSO является сообществом без управления, у него нету главного уже долгое время. Главная компания SO забрала у нас отличного комьюнити менеджера, который жил этим сообществом, он проводил сходки, вел стримы с участниками, показывал как сообщество живет и дышит. Он решал многие вопросы, которые сейчас попросту не решить, мы не можем начать выборы, мы не можем изменить что либо, мы даже не можем поменять справку, все это делается долго, через кучу проблем. После того, как Николас покинул RuSO, а потом и вовсе SO, нам не дали адекватного менеджера, у нас нету адекватной прямой связи с SO, да и о нас по сути, забыли. У нас нету всех тех наворотов, что есть на EnSO, нету той рекламы, что делается на EnSO, у нас нету ничего, нас попросту не продвигают. Вот допустим, коллективы - это инструмент, где компания может создать свой "подраздел", со своим набором участников, и пр... Будет? Нет, ибо SO не сотрудничает с СНГ компаниями. На мете вон новый вид формы отправки ответа, через пару лет может быть дойдет что-то такое и до нас. Про аналог GPT, который встроен в сам SO я вообще молчу. И это ведь уже не первый год такое творится.
Идем дальше...
Модераторы
В последние активные дни Николаса в роли менеджера RuSO, у нас были, на мой взгляд, самые лучшие модераторы! А именно Suvitruf и A K, они делали все ради сообщества, они тонну сообщений перелопатили, тонну меток изменили, они создавали "каноничные закрывашки", объединяя ряд одинаковых дубликатов одним полноценным, правильным, хорошим ответом, они находили к каждому случаю индивидуальный подход, видно было, что эти люди были не просто болванчиками, который бездумно тыкали на все подряд, а это были люди, которые ценили и уважали сообщество и они делали даже больше, чем просто модератор. Ну а что видим сейчас? У нас уже куча тем на мете про нарушения модераторов, про всякие отказы и необоснованные действия. Не, я не спорю, свою задачу криво-косо, ребята да выполняют, только вот большего они ничего не делают, я не вижу, чтобы они хоть как-то развивали сообщество, поднимали темы, участвовали хоть как-то. На мете я вижу лишь их ответы, которые они где-то там совместно готовят и все, а порой и вовсе, игнор полный, нету вообще желания решать какие либо проблемы. Давайте допустим взглянем, какие вопросы, и сколько задавал на мете A K и Suvitruf, а потом смотрим на текущий состав aepot и αλεχολυτ (тут кстати весьма интересно, как по мне, модераторство только убило желания человека, ибо после выборов его актив, как по мне, резко упал). Собственно, вы видите хоть какие либо телодвижения тех, у кого есть "власть", есть связи с вышестоящими? Я вот нет. Ладно инициативы и связь, фиг с ним, но хотя бы порядок наводится? Бывают случаи, где сами модераторы вместо того, чтобы найти дубликат и на него закрыть, плодят очередной ответ... О каком тогда развитие сообщества мы можем говорить?
А теперь, давайте поговорим и про людей...
Люди
Вот я часто слышу в последнее время "убиваем новичков, ай ай", а вы про "старичков" подумали? Ну вот хоть кто либо? Вот я сюда, на RuSO пришел только с одной целью - обучение, изначально мне сайт это давал, ибо тут были отличные люди, которые писали качественные, развернутые, интересные ответы. Я очень благодарен был VladD, этот человек не просто отвечал на мои вопросы, но и некое время вел мой "детский" ПЕТ проект, показывая на нем как надо, переписывая мой нелепый код. Это было одним из самых значимых в моей жизни временем, ибо он мне помог пробить стену, которую я долго не мог пробить сам. Я очень благодарен Андрей NOP за все его отличные ответы по WPF, да и C# в целом, благодаря им я очень многое познал самостоятельно в WPF. Также я благодарен A K, ответы которого также очень сильно помогли мне в понимании C#. Есть ряд и других людей, которые активно раньше давали ответы, заполняли тем самым SO качественными и полезными знаниями. Но увы, часть из них поссорилась с SO, часть ушла по другим причинам, часть перешла в "пассивный режим". По вопросам C# сейчас от силы человека 2, может 3 активных, а ответы уже не такого качества, как было это раньше, увы. Ну и чему тут учиться тогда? От кого получать знания? В год может быть 1 ответ будет полезный, да и все, вот и вся "польза", которую я получу от SO.
Зато "новички" нам важнее, да? Те, что не могут пользоваться поиском, не пробуют самостоятельно. Те, что задают каждый день вопросы из серии "как какать" (по другому я их назвать не могу). Те, кто плевать хотел на IT, язык, сообщество, ему лишь бы получить ответ, скопировать и забыть про это, как про страшный сон. Да да, такие люди нам очень важны, мы должны сделать все, чтобы они пользовались SO как можно дольше! Только вот вы задавались вопросом, а зачем им это? Зачем им ваша социальность, рейтинг, зачем им делиться с вами своими знаниями? SO был, есть, да и всегда будет местом, куда человек заходит чисто решить свои проблемы, ну а сейчас эти проблемы решает за него искусственный интеллект. Вот вам и новички... Основное SO это компенсирует новыми разработками, привлечения бизнеса (на вопросы которого GPT еще не знает ответа), а мы такое можем? Нет конечно.
Ответ на вопросы
Ну и чтоб это не было как просто "крик души", давайте хоть отвечу на поставленные вопросы...

Я не стал реже посещать SO. Я, наверно, сейчас на первых местах по кол-во подряд посещенных дней. Я каждый день захожу, каждые наверно минут 30, это уже привычка у меня такая.

Если речь про "реже задаю вопросы" - я их всегда задавал по минимуму, только в крайних случаях, ибо почти всегда пытаюсь разобраться самостоятельно, ну а если пару недель не получается, тогда  может быть да, иду на SO задавать вопрос. НО, тут самое важное... Я не всегда получаю тут нужный мне ответ, ибо те, кто "в теме", ушли с SO... Думаю много из вас сталкивалось с таким, что если вопрос чуть сложнее "базы", то вы вряд-ли на него получите адекватный ответ, увы. "2+2=?" - набежит человек десять отвечающих, а если "Как работает квантовый компьютер" - от силы может быть 1, и то напишет в комментариях что-то. Утрирую конечно. Вывод: Для профессионала SO стал бесполезным.

Если речь про "реже отвечаю" - а на что? Я C# разработчик, давайте откроем метку и посмотрим на вопросы, большинство из них будут подобны этому, где человек просто не знает как вызвать свойство класса. Ну и что, писать ответ с одной строкой newArray.GetCountArr? Извините, но я против такого, ибо я не вижу пользы для SO как в ответе, так и в вопросе. Собственно из "ответа" это перекочевывает в комментарий, которые я и оставляю чаще всего, ибо просто нет хороших вопросов, "старички" ушли, а "новички" задают постоянно "как какать", вот и вся причина.



Фактор снижение активности - то, что RuSO забросили, мы не комьюнити, мы толпа людей, где у каждого свои правила, свои порядки, свои взгляды. Кто-то считает SO форумом, другие считают это базой. Мы были комьюнити, когда у нас был главный менеджер, который объединял всячески народ, встречами, трансляциями, всякими новостями со статистикой, решением всяких вопросов, и так далее. Сейчас этого нет, сейчас мы для главного SO просто балласт, который не удивлюсь, если в скором времени они решат прикрыть.
Также естественно, GPT посодействовал этому, о чем я написал выше. Проще спросить там, чем идти сюда и надеяться, что дадут нужный тебе ответ.

Повторю, ничего мы, простые люди, с этим сделать не сможем. Вы пойдете рекламировать на другие ресурсы SO? Сомневаюсь. Вы пойдете по компаниям, чтобы те здесь развивали свое комьюнити? Сомневаюсь. Вы заставите разработчиков SO внедрить сюда весь функционал? Ух вряд-ли. А может сможете заманить обратно ушедших "старичков"? Думаю поезд ушел. Короче, не нам с вами развивать SO, это может сделать только компания, которая будет тесно сотрудничать с РУ комьюнити.


Собственно, вот вам мое мнение на этот счет.

Интересно, что уходили активные участники из-за конфликтов именно с Николасом, а также с некоторыми ныне ушедшими модераторами. Теперь, когда их нет, что-то никто назад не набижал... Как живое подтверждение того, что сообщество потерять легче, чем построить.

ибо тут были отличные люди, которые писали качественные, развернутые, интересные ответы И сейчас такие участники тоже есть, и не один по сишарпу: tym32167, Alexander Petrov, CrazyElf, aepot и многие другие, всех не перечислишь... Сравнение с прошлым создает впечатление, будто "раньше и сахар был слаще", но ведь у каждого времени есть свои люди, которые помогают сообществу, поддерживают новичков и вдохновляют на развитие пет-проектов. Сравнивать прошлое и настоящее — значит обесценивать то, что у нас есть сейчас.

@Dev18 "всех не перечислишь" - вы только что это сделали. И то, последний ответ от tym32167 - сентябрь, по сравнению с тем, что было раньше, у него SO также на режиме "ReadOnly". Александр аналогично, больше комментарии, очень редко ответы, да и ответы из серии "вот код, разбирайтесь". Раньше довольно много было качественных ответов, допустим таких. Сейчас вы когда в последний раз видели подобное? На моей памяти, из последних, качественных и хороших ответов, это этот, 21 год...

убиваем новичков, ай ай => потому что для старичков --- ...Думаю поезд ушел. Легче привлечь внимание нового, чем уговорить старого... //а человек так устроен, что когда заново заиграло, то и старые подтянутся на огонек... //но с одним я наверно соглашусь, и кстати именно поэтому я и создала этот вопрос, потому что, если SO увидит, что умерло сообщество то так и будет... => ...в скором времени они решат прикрыть.

вы только что это сделали. => нет, есть rotabor, MSDN.WhiteKnight, да и есть еще и другие, если прям так надо могу этому время выделить прям...но не это же суть, вы там двоих назвали всего //также хорошие ответы рождаются от хороших вопросов...тут как бы круг получается... нет ручек нет конфет...

@Dev18 Ваше право соглашаться или нет. Я лишь высказал то, что увидел тут за 8 лет. Лично для меня сайт стал бесполезным, увы, хотя раньше это было не так. Причины две, о них я расписал в своём ответе. Вы "новичок", вам нравиться, устраивает все - супер. Но если допустим вас вдруг выберут модератором (а вы вроде этого хотите), то я скорей всего уйду, ибо раздел " модераторы". Такие вот дела)

увы, хотя раньше это было не так.  => потому что раньше вас вдохновляли на пет проекты вы были тем самым новичком... Я не "новичок", на сайте 7с лишним лет, из которых ридОнли было чаще раньше, но потом для меня открылась мета...как раз таки в феврале 2022 года...  скорей всего уйду => каждый делает свой выбор сам. про раздел "модераторы" вообще не понятно, какой именно абзац там надо мне отметить? а вы вроде этого хотите => вообще ни разу, но если что то люблю, пытаюсь это спасти, если в моих силах... такие вот дела)

@Dev18 Поверьте, это не так. Я очень быстро преодолел статус "новичка", после чего сам начал давать качественные, отличные ответы. Это было интересно, увлекательно. После вопросы вдруг превратились в "2+2, сколько будет?" Ну и это длится до сих пор. Так что, дело не в опыте, а в контенте, что даёт мне SO. Какой вам абзац? Скорей всю суть целиком, там про то, какой модератор хороший, а какой нет. По вашей активности и комментариям... Я не вижу от вас чего либо полезного, порой наоборот, разводите только флуд. Но это уже совсем другая тема...

Всё чётко написал. Как есть! Единственное я бы немного поправил, что во времена Николаса тоже было тыща мнений от тыщи людей как должен выглядеть сайт. И всё так же каждый тянул одеяло на себя. Николас разве что чуть больше всё это сдерживал... А так - всё в точку

"Комьюнити менеджер и RuSO на самоуправлении" - вот если бы хотя бы нормальное самоуправление было (с ограниченным сроком модераторов на посту, обязательной ротацией), то можно было бы и без выделенного менеджера обходиться (как мне кажется). "Кто-то считает SO форумом, другие считают это базой." - ну тут точно не форум в обычном смысле, но обычно тут противопоставляют решение проблем и наполнение базы знаний. Но это ложная дихотомия - можно одновременно решать насущные проблемы участников, и таким образом наполнять базу. Так QnA сайты и работают. Но с вашим выводом в целом я согласен)

@insolor "Без выделенного менеджера" нет адекватной связи с компанией, нету ее поддержки в виде оперативно решения вопросов, коммуникации с сообществом, да даже мерч компании на встречах не получить. Также, без менеджера нас просто некому защищать в случае чего. Уверен, что Николас будучи сотрудником так или иначе отстаивал русское сообщество в тех или иных вопросах. Так что, в таких крупных проектах, как SO, должен быть свой сотрудник, говорящий на языке данного сообщества и решающий исключительно вопросы конкретного сообщества. Без него вряд-ли на чистом "самоуправлении" можно вытянуть.

Ну да, коммуникация с компанией нужна. Мерч и встречи меня не особо волнуют, но в остальном согласен, так мы практически ничего не сможем сделать.

"убиваем новичков, ай ай", и при этом вы говорите: "тут были отличные люди...", ну так я про это и пишу! Надо нам становится отличными, чтобы тем кто сейчас сюда приходит, было также приятно как вам!

@чистов_n Честно, я не вижу "убийства новичков", о котором все говорят, наоборот, я вижу убийство "старичков", что в разы хуже. Для многих "убийство новичков" - это когда тот не может нормально сформулировать вопрос и его (вопрос) за это закрывают; когда новичок кидает чисто задание, без путей решения и вообще каких либо самостоятельных попыток; когда код скриншотом кидается; ну и так далее. Ну а теперь вопрос... А разве тут "система" виновата, или сам человек? Почему меня ("старичка") заставляют подстраиваться под таких? Ну а если человек старается, то ему будет "также приятно, как и мне"

Пока читал сам вопрос,.. в голове созрели тезисы для целой поэмы-петиции о том что не так, но хорошо, что ваш комментарий уже вобрал в кучу практически всё, что хотелось высказать. В мелких и малозначительных деталях я возможно и не соглашусь (нюансы), но в целом — "+"


Почему вы стали реже использовать ru.SO?

Отвечаю. Потому что стало сильно меньше вопросов, на которые я могу ответить. Тех, которые по тому, что я знаю. (Например вопросы по самому Python, не по каким-то библиотекам)

Какие факторы, на ваш взгляд, повлияли на снижение активности?

Конечно ChatGPT. Но, боюсь, ещё и наше с вами обращение к новичками. Мы не удосуживаемся всё им объяснить, как исправить их  вопросы, а иногда просто молча закрывем вопрос, а что ещё хуже, смеёмся над ними!

Какой формат привлечения пользователей был бы полезен?

Думаю изменив своё обращение к новичкам, мы сможем оставить их здесь, мотивировать зарабатывать репутацию и приглашать друзей.

Возможно это звучит как призыв, но я написал как смог.

Я реже заходить не стал, но ответы стал давать реже. Тут сказывается несколько факторов:

Когда ты только пришёл на СО, то каждый новый вопрос кажется важным, хочется на него ответить, если знаешь. А когда провёл тут несколько лет, то уже понимаешь, что большинство существенных вопросов давно уже были отвечены, и всё, что ты можешь - это поискать дубли к очередному заданному кем-то вопросу. Тот, кто задавал вопрос, наверняка не пользовался поиском. А ты и без поиска помнишь, что на этот вопрос уже было 100500+ ответов, и часть из них были твои собственные. Всё, что нужно - это поискать эти вопросы, найти подходящий и отметить новый вопрос как дубликат. Интересно ли это? Да не очень то. Работать поисковиком из-за этого, что сам автор вопроса поленился это сделать. Рутина какая-то.

Языковая специфика.

Какие-то языки активно развиваются, массово изучаются новичками, про них появляются новые вопросы, причём обычно на них не сложно ответить. Это касается Python, например. Каждый день с десяток вопросов да будет. И не все они дубликаты. Ошибок и граблей разных много бывает, есть над чем подумать хотя бы немного. Ну или взять, к примеру, JavaScript.
А какие-то языки остаются достаточно нишевыми, все существенные ответы на вопросы по ним даны ещё много лет назад. Это, как вы понимаете, C#. Да, он тоже развивается, но джунов в нём не так много появляется. И все их вопросы давно отвечены. Если и появляются реальные какие-то вопросы по C#, то их очень мало и они очень специфические. Поэтому я очень понимаю фрустрацию тех, кто ограничивается тут C#. Это реально пустыня какая-то. Отвечать не на что, а если и есть на что, то в этом нужно сидеть разбираться, а потом это ещё и выльется в холивар, как на самом деле нужно писать, а как не надо. Сегодня был один такой как-раз характерный вопрос с комментариями.
Или вот взять к примеру глубокое машинное обучение или ещё какие-то такие специфические темы. Специалистов тут по ним практически вообще нет, а темы сложные, нужно вникать, разбираться. Получается замкнутый круг. Спецов нет - никто не отвечает - задавать вопросы без толку - никто не ходит сюда за этим - нет спецов.



Что со всем этим делать? За всех не скажу, но я лично стараюсь регулярно залазить в какие-то смежные темы, понемногу учить то, в чём я не спец. Да, я хорошо знаю Python, C#, машинное обучение (без глубокого погружения в нейросети), базово JavaScript и React. Но стараюсь почитывать вопросы и по Java, GoLang и прочему, и иногда даже даю ответы в этих темах. Таким образом я развиваюсь и это помогает мне поддерживать интерес к СО. А вот что должен сам СО сделать, чтобы сохранять интерес - это нужно думать, не такая и простая это тема - как удержать людей и расширить аудиторию. Хотя казалось бы, куда ещё идти за ответами по программированию, если не на СО в первую очередь. )
При этом, если бы я не писал тут ответы на вопросы, то как читатель я не часто тут ответы ищу. Сейчас очень много хорошей документации, таториалов и прочих материалов. Часто СО помогает только с какими-то ad hoc проблемами и решениями. Ну, они тоже нужны, но бывает, что далеко не каждый день.

Очень хороший ответ, предпоследний абзац прям особенно хороший =)

Отлично. А вот в этом   "Часто СО помогает только с какими-то ad hoc проблемами и решениями"  как раз вся его прелесть (предназначение, если угодно), именно в этом а не в какой-то "базе  знаний". Причем на днях был как раз этот самый случай (правда, вопрос не задавал, но поиск в гугле привел именно на ruSO). Надо было найти одинаковые  строки, а uniq -c вылетел из головы. Когда увидел этот -c здесь  в каком-то ответе про что-то похожее, то сразу стало очевидно sort file | unic -c | awk '$1 != 1' (и счетчик повторения как вишенка на торте)

В тему развития - хорошая практика, но... Не вижу тут у нас на руСО вопросов про крипту (и я не про лудилово и скам, а про технологию), нету про машинное обучение. Насколько я понимаю эти темы очень привлекают молодых и горячих, но они не приходят сюда за ответами, не спрашивают. И почитать тут особо нечего. Именно того, что сейчас двигает индустрию, темы почему люди приходят в профессию, нет на руСО. Гнусавить старчески можно на новые технологие, но отрицать и не замечать их не стоит)

@Dmitry Ну почему нет машинного обучения. Есть, но мало и редко. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5

@CrazyElf таки я и про это ) 925 вопросов, 49 за год. Не отражает того бума, который происходит в этой теме. Я, например, вообще взял университетский курс по этой и еще нескольким смежным темам. На каждой встрече все только и трещат об этом, Нобелевские премии начали раздавать за модели машинного обучения. А у нас штиль( Так не хочется сравнивать с enSO, но там только за неделю 86 вопросов

@Dmitry Ну, есть такое. Я об этом тоже в ответе написал. За специализированными штуками ходят на специализированные форумы в основном. Кроме того, видимо, СО считается больше программистским форумом, а в ML вопросы часто не про программирование, а про методологию. )

@CrazyElf тема реализации с помощью программных и аппаратных средств тоже не раскрыта. Пример из первых вопросов. Те кто интересуется этой темой сразу сталкнутся с большим количеством данных и необходимостью оптимизации и поиска подходов и решений именно в реализации

Давненько я тут ничего не писал.
Сначала, хотел ответить то, как чувствую, но потом понял, что это ощущение может быть крайне субъективно и решил все это проверить.
(На самом деле просто вспомнил, что наше сообщество очень любит графики))
Количество вопросов на ruSO

Количество ответов на ruSO

После того как посмотрел статистику на нашем сайте решил сравнить со статистикой на enSO, чтобы понять что именно повлияло на такое положение вещей
Количество вопросов на enSO

Количество ответов на enSO

Графики ruSO повторяют поведение аналогичных графиков на enSO.
Это совершенно точно не локальный тренд и не нужно обвинять бедных модераторов и нового CM -  им и так со всех сторон прилетает.

Новые пользователи
Вы могли заметить, что я не приложил динамику новых пользователей на ruSO/enSO.
Я их оставил на десерт, ибо тут неоднозначная информация.
Количество новых пользователей на ruSO

Количество новых пользователей на enSO

Количество новых пользователей что на ruSO, что на enSO растёт как не в себя.
Это могут быть как реальные пользователи, так и боты...(и в последнее вериться даже больше)

Мое мнение
Community Manager
Активный CM это безусловно здорово, тем не менее чем больше Николас погружался в дела StackExchange, тем меньше мы его видели в сообществе, а в какой-то момент и вовсе перестали... Мы многие годы справлялись и без него. И как по мне  - неплохо справлялись.
Менеджер != Лидер
Я хочу дополнить одного из пользователей, который ссылался на отсутствие Николаса ... Такой комментарий был не один, но во многих из них было два обязательных аспекта отсутствие CM и негативный опыт с этим связанный. Но я эту ситуацию вижу немного по другому. Николас какое-то время был не только менеджером сообщества, но и его лидером. И в контексте данного вопроса пользователи ссылаются на опыт связанный не с отсутствием человека, который выполняет функции менеджера (он то как раз таки у нас сейчас есть, в отличии от ситуации, которая была пару лет назад), а на опыт связанный с отсутствием лидера сообщества.
Но здесь я Вас могу успокоить... ибо эта позиция неформальная, более того она не ограничена количеством мест. Лидер, это человек, который может оказывать влияние на сообщество и им может стать любой его участник.
Компания
Есть мнение о том, что компания негативно влияет на развитие ресурса  и местами я согласен с данным утверждением, но я не согласен с тем, что сообщество не может без компании. Я напомню, что изначально сообщество собралось вокруг ресурса, который назывался хеш-код, который уже был давным давно куплен компанией stackexchange. И на момент покупки часть пользователей тоже отвалилась, но на их место пришли новые и активность только увеличилась. И в тот момент пересмотренные ценности и правила только бустанули развитие нашего сообщества
Сообщество может существовать, не соглашаясь с политикой компании.
Я не отрицаю, что эта компания может влиять на нас как на сообщество, но при этом я не хочу и не буду перекладывать на него всю ответственность. Как и не буду перетягивать свое негативное отношение к компании на сообщество, которое собралось вокруг его продукта и призываю других участников придерживаться той же стратегии.
Модераторы
Наше сообщество является самоуправляемым и оно изначально таким планировалось. Модераторы уходят сами, модераторы снимаются, на модераторов может давить сообщество, модераторы избираются сообществом.
У сообщества есть рычаги влияния на мод.состав (как они работают это другой разговор).
Я возможно сейчас покажусь жестким, но у нас тот состав, которого мы заслуживаем ... ни больше ни меньше.
Можно жаловаться, а можно пойти и что-то сделать для сообщества.
Текущее состояние
Политика компании
Тренд на снижение начался до пика популярности chatGPT и он был связан с политикой компании StackExchange, коммерциализацией сервиса, постепенным снижением прав её участников.
Как и в случае с модераторами, тут можно жаловаться и пытаться воевать с корпорацией, а можно работать над компенсацией в рамках сообщества.
ChatGPT и прочие LLM
ChatGPT тоже неслабо повлиял на пикирующий вниз график.
Окном входа для получения ответов на вопросы стали чаты и ассистенты в IDE'шках
Моё отношение к текущему состоянию
Сколько себя помню - все жаловались

на тысячи однотипных вопросов
на то, что приходят студенты и новички и просят за них решать лабораторные и прочие задачи
на то, что люди не умеют гуглить

И вот пришел ChatGPT и все это исправил)
Я всегда говорил, что SO это чуть больше чем просто ответы на вопросы, что это сообщество, что это мы с Вами ... и как мне кажется за ежедневной рутиной, за бумом курсов по разработке и тем какое влияние это оказало на индустрию в целом и на наше сообщество в частности и за последующим бумом прикладного ИИ все чуть подзабыли чем мы являемся и для чего мы все здесь собрались (МНЕНИЕ СУГУБО СУБЪЕКТИВНО).
Все это ни хорошо, ни плохо...это естественный ход истории.
Мы можем опустить руки и слить это сообщество, а можем сами строить сообщество снизу, сами задавать интересные и новые вопросы, сами на них отвечать, самим поддерживать сообщество.
Я данное сообщество люблю, пусть и не всегда у меня на него хватает времени, но я понимаю, что мы сами можем многое.
Сообщество умирает, когда у его участников пропадает мотивация и желание его поддерживать и в непростые для этого сообщества времена мне не хочется акцентировать внимание на негативных факторах, разделять и разобщать сообщество, обвинять кого-то.
Что делать?
Всё что мы можем сделать это сконцентрироваться на том, что мы можем сделать для того, чтобы это сообщество и дальше жило и развивалось.
И тут все просто, поскольку это и так описано в ценностях нашего сообщества

открытость
доброжелательность
тяга к новым знаниям

Все в наших руках

Каждый из Вас может поделиться новыми знаниями в своих постах.
Каждый может заонбордить новичка, помочь ему с оформлением или формулировкой вопроса.
Каждый может сделать что-то чтобы замотивировать старых участников.
Каждый может найти и поделиться чем-то
Каждый может замотивировать кого-нибудь присоединиться к сообществу
Каждый может рассказать своим коллегам о ценностях, из-за которых вы остались в данном сообществе


протестую!!! я не могу два плюсика поставить, а то и три!!!!!!!! Вы сейчас сделали огромную работу, абстрогировавшись от своего мнения и дав оценку и такую точную и верную со стороны. Я просто снимаю шляпу. Это невероятно как написан ответ, я все ждала что-то такое. (аж мурашки) это дорого стоит сказать правду. Каждый абзац продуман.

@Dev18, отвлекался на работу, поэтому продуман далеко не до конца... как правило в течении дня еще какие-то правки и апдейты в ответы отсылаю и через день он устаканивается

Отлично написано! И правильно -- на самом деле все в наших руках, в доброжелательном и ответственном отношении друг к другу

Почему стал реже использовать (на самом деле чаще, но в режиме read-only)

Простых вопросов стало меньше, предположительно, благодаря нейросетям (из-за нейросетей). На сложные вопросы ответить не могу. Поэтому пока ушёл совершенствоваться... Кстати, частично с помощью старых ответов, за которые всегда голосую.

Ещё как причина — некоторая работа уходит коту под хвост. Например, авторы вопросов и ответ не принимают, и в комментариях ничего не пишут.... И непонятно: ты помог человеку или нет? Ладно, пусть мой ответ поможет, тем, кто в будущим с той же проблемой столкнётся...

Ещё обидно, что старания во благо сайта упираются в то, что надо позвать сотрудника... А сотрудник то ли не понимает, что надо сделать (хотя вроде ВСЁ НА ЕГО ЯЗЫКЕ НАПИСАЛИ), то ли просто халтурит (уже к этому склоняюсь).


UPD: есть ещё причина. Сейчас всё большую популярность набирают онлайн-курсы. К сожалению, многие их студенты пришли исключительно из-за красивой рекламы. Большая часть этих обучающихся реально учиться не хотят — они хотят только большую зарплату. И как только у них что-то не получается, они приходят на ruSO. Вот только они настолько ленивы и беспомощны, что ни запроса в гугл послать, ни (тем более) задать у нас качественный вопрос. Как правило эти лентяи и сами помощи не получают, после чего не задают вопросов, и понижают количество отвечающих, которые от них просто устают. В результате действительно целеустремлённые и талантливые новички тоже страдают: отвечающих мало, их вопросы пропадают в ленте вопросов от лентяев. По итогу падает и количество вопросов, и количество ответов...
Что надо сделать?

Надо добавить куда-нибудь на видное место ссылку на чат, чтобы юзеры понимали, что такая форма взаимодействия здесь тоже есть. Многих отталкивает серьёзность платформы, иногда действительно хочется задать вопрос, на который невозможно дать объективный ответ. Сначала может показаться, что это разрушит ruSO, раз все в чат перейдут. На самом деле нет. В чат лишь отлично впишутся те самые запрещённые вопросы, на обычные вопросы в чате вряд ли кто-то будет отвечать, пошлют задавать вопрос.
НАДО ПОЧИНИТЬ СПРАВКУ. Новички не соблюдают правила сайта? А ПРАВИЛА САЙТА НАПИСАНЫ АБЫ-КАК МНОГО ЛЕТ НАЗАД


Насчет увеличения популярности чата, тут проблема в том, что кто-то тогда должен будет его модерировать, а организовать это нелегко. Раньше, в 2017-2018, чат был более популярен без ссылки на видном месте, но при этом в нем было много драм насчет модерации, например: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7688/ . Постоянно звучало "чат плохой, нужен альтернативный чат на другой платформе". И затем альтернативный чат был создан, на Zulip, но в итоге и он умер...

@MSDN.WhiteKnight проблема модерации не решается уничтожением. Надо будет модерировать — выберем ещё модераторов, желающих не так уж и мало, см последние выборы. Можно спецмодераторов именно для чата назначить. К тому же раньше, насколько я понял, были конфликты основателя с сообществом, сейчас это уже невозможно.

"Простых вопросов стало меньше"  — IMHO, но всё наоборот. На большинство вопросов либо даже рука не тянется отвечать (несформулированный бред требующий кучу пилотажных уточнений, пока вытянешь сам вопрос, либо специфические/позабытые всеми движки и нюансы из первобытных времён). Заметил за собой, что стал отписываться от "простых" вопросов к которым лепят всякие "нелепые" теги. Например? Вопрос о javascript в целом, но всякие UI в тегах, до которых мне нет дела и которыми мусорят встречаются куда чаще, но в виде "Почему нельзя пропатчить?"

@stylok это не простые вопросы. Это просто некачественные.

@MSDN.WhiteKnight: Смею всё же напомнить, что альтчат был создан после многочисленных банов активных участников. Драм можно было бы легко избежать, если бы Николас и Паша не банили всех направо и налево, когда у них заканчивалась аргументация. В бане как-то не получается общаться в чате (удивительно, правда?), поэтому мы и ушли в чат, где нас не могут забанить. С уходом SOпротивления с сайта стало нечего обсуждать в альтчате, поэтому он и умер. Он был нужен лишь из-за банов.


Почему вы стали реже использовать ru.SO?

Потому что я за последний месяц заработал два бана:

первый общий из-за известных разборок по поводу "немых" минусов, которые по большому счёту свелись к паре банов для участников просто из-за лишнего шума

второй свежий в очередях проверок из-за голоса за переоткрытие вопроса, закрытого модератором Grundy.  Также бана за это "преступление" был удостоен один из двух проголосовавших за переоткрытие.



Какие факторы, на ваш взгляд, повлияли на снижение активности?

На снижение моей личной активности повлиял ряд факторов:

уменьшение количества вопросов по причинам, озвученным в посте "Раньше было намного больше".
косная политика модерации на сайте.


Какой формат привлечения пользователей был бы полезен?

А есть ли смысл в привлечении новых пользователей?  "Никто не вливает молодого вина в мехи ветхие".

Мы тут за один переживали, а вас второй раз... Ньдя... А зачем за голос "за" даётся бан???//и зачем одному их двух, а не всем троим... Если запрещено "за" голосовать???а на что отражался второй бан? Я потому что не заметила

На какой срок вас банили во второй раз? Это был общий бан или ограничение на определённые действия?

@Chaos_Sower, мой бан только на очереди проверок, но сразу на все

@NowhereMan, а я и смотрю, что в очереди проверок лампочка красненьким горит — некому проверять((

@NowhereMan, слушайте, а задайте отдельный вопрос на Мете, мне вот тоже эта вся ситуация непонятна (я видел закрытый вопрос). Решать вам, но мне вот кажется, что с этим надо разобраться

@Dev18 Только такое сообщение на странице проверок: "Следующие проверки были обработаны некорректно:[ссылка] Мы подозреваем, что вы на самом деле не осуществляете проверки.  Плохие проверки негативно влияют на сообщество. Пожалуйста, уделяйте достаточно внимания каждой проверке в дальнейшем."  -- в общем, если тебя в чём-то заподоздрили, никто цацкаться не будет -- получай банхаммером и достигай просветления самостоятельно.  Обратной связи с модераторами как таковой нет.

@Dev18, я не вижу обратной связи от модераторов в топ 5 вопросах на мете, которые касаются их деятельности напрямую. Про тех кто выше — смешно писать. Только открытие отдельного конкретного вопроса сможет привлечь внимание (в вашем случае, Dev18, это помогло, и вам ответили! Так, к слову)

По порядку оставлю мнение на ваши вопросы, хоть их и не один

Всегда стоит попробовать предпринять шаги, если вас как-то задевает эта тема
Ничего страшного не произойдет, если политика сайта скажет, что вы не правы.
Рассылка по эл почте уже давно не эффективна. На своем примере. Я не читаю почту, от слова совсем, она рассортирована до безобразия и лишние письма летят сразу в топку. Не важен источник (доверенный или нет), если я письмо не жду, то его у меня и не будет


Рассылка.....не эффективна.На своем примере => это немного узко. => в плане => Примеров столько же сколько и людей)))Если лично мне придет письмо от стекОверФлоу, я сразу побегу читать, даже, если не жду)))

@Dev18 мой пример исходит из того, что я работаю в этой сфере достаточно давно. Он может быть не показателен, но люди вокруг меня действуют примерно также по очень простой причине => большое количество информации. Нам есть чем заняться и время ограничено. На сам СО заходишь чаще, по разным причинам, и встроить вопрос в интерфейс сайта, на мой взгляд эффективней в разы. Плюс возможность реализовать опрос по фокусгруппам. Пример, новореги (фидбек от первого использования), старожилы, любители тревоги разбирать и тд

мне кажется что не хватает нам социальной составляющей и хорошего адекватного дружелюбия. Я давно не общался с новичками, которые и должны приходить и рыскать тут, но лет 5 назад, они как огня боялись зарегаться здесь или спросить чего. Некоторые так и остались анонимными читателями. Нет культуры общения, нет идеи, которая бы привлекала сюда людей, нет перспектив для раскачки акка. Может кто знает, спрашивают сейчас на собеседовании профиль на СО или нет?

Вставлю и я свои три копейки...
На мой взгляд падение интересак SO происходит по следующим причинам:

нет работы с сообществом (собрания в реале, конкурсы, стримы и т.д. и т.п.).;
наплевательское отношение к людям, которые вложили/вкладывают свой опыт/силы/нервы в наполнение сайта;
"сюси-пуси" с новичками и дебильными вопросами, которые ищутся в поисковике на раз-два, что, в свою очередь, переполняет ленту вопросов и до интересного вопроса может и не хватить нервов/времени долистать;
сама платформа, а вернее её возможности, а ещё вернее их отсутствие (песочница для кода, шаблоны ответов, возможности редактора и т.д. и т.п.)
самое главное - развитие/доступность AI. На данный момент на локальной машине  можно за несколько минут развернуть локальную нейронку, которая будет давать приемлимые результаты на 80% вопросов.

Из-за всего выше приведённого, лично я, не вижу причин/стимулов/резона/интереса пользоваться SO вне зависимости от локали. На enSO тебе прилетит либо куча минусов, либо закроют вопрос со ссылкой на левую тему, либо он просто будет висеть без ответа. Здесь ситуация ещё хуже, так как многие, кто мог поделиться опытом уже, скажем так, им не делится...
В своё время был хороший ресурс, но когда людям стало важнее не профессиональные вопросы-ответы, а кто, кого каким местоимением называет и прочая бредятина не относящаяся к IT, какая-то бюрократизация что-ли, то и стало происходить то, что до сих пор происходит.


Почему вы стали реже использовать ru.SO?

Утомили снобизм и формализм некоторых старожилов, их бесконечное ворчание по поводу "вопросов низкого качества" от новичков (удивительно, что ничего не знающие новички задают вопросы низкого качества, кто бы мог ожидать такое) и т.д. Заходишь в вопрос, а там в комментах бурления по поводу того, насколько плох новичок, если не смог составить правильный запрос для поисковика, и куда ему следует отправиться. А иногда бурления в духе "зачем вы отвечаете на этот вопрос!?" Ну серьёзно, выглядит это донельзя токсично.

Какие факторы, на ваш взгляд, повлияли на снижение активности?

Рост качества ответов от ChatGPT. Да, до сих пор многие ответы там нуждаются в перепроверке, зачастую они неверны или неполностью верны. Но они покрывают все потребности новичков.

Какой формат привлечения пользователей был бы полезен?

А он нужен? Тут постоянно старожилы и некоторые модераторы высказывают, что нужны качественные вопросы для "составления базы данных вопросов". Самые простые и популярные вопросы уже отвечены. Новичков уже не получится перетянуть, они скорее пойдут у нейросетей спрашивать - это быстрее, а зачастую не хуже по качеству (а иногда даже лучше). А привлечь опытных со стороны тоже навряд ли удастся, т.к. SO банально не может предложить им ничего ценного.


Потому, что когда я захожу на главную страницу, то вместо новых вопросов вижу пачку исправлений старых, различными умными людьми.

см. п.1

Добавьте новую функцию, чтобы можно было не только исправлять чужие вопросы и ответы, но и писать вопросы и ответы за других пользователей и тогда вы сами сможете восстановить активность!



используйте фильтры, очень удобно, чтоб настроить вашу главную страницу

но и писать вопросы и ответы за других пользователей => это как? так?=> https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1597973/264178 //или речь о множестве аккаунтов от одного человека? так такое делается максимум на начальном этапе, чтоб раскрутить платформу, а сейчас такое только собьет с толку, тк это некорректная статистика будет...

@Dev18, вы считаете, что перевод ответа на русский язык тождествен "написанию ответа за другого пользователя"?

@NowhereMan, я вообще не поняла эту фразу, а отвечающий так и не ответил, а на момент комментария, я проверку вашей правки смотрела... Вот и привела пример...

Кому-то неймётся минусовать неудобные вопросы и замечания, но как раз сегодня вспомнил (писал как-то для себя мимоходом фильтр для uBlock) чтобы избавиться от "некромантических" вопросов,  @Dev18 не даст соврать.) Все эти археологические бОяны, дабы организовать движуху, потыкав палкой в комьюнити того не стоят. Да и некроманты уже не те. Попытаюсь, не дословно, но вкратце пересказать, что — "вопросы можно поднимать из "инферно", если тому есть причина:   актуальность + И/ИЛИ не было ответа или язык достаточно изменился для того, чтобы улучшить сам ответ", но при этом автор вопроса "жив".)

Вот сегодня, и ходить далеко не надо... вся главная залита древними и далеко не интересными "помоями" с вполне готовыми ответами откопанными @чистов_n. А с учётом игнорируемых мною тегов, более чем наполовину. Зачем?! Пришлось добавить в блокировщик ещё один фильтр на этого "археолога".

И, прощу прощения за беспокойство вас лично, но... просто ветка удобная (это будет теперь моим блогом.)) это уже не только утомляет, что можно исправить личными фильтрами в "блокировщике", а сам факт того что на это реагируют и как... мой комментарий под  "новым" бессмысленным ответом не несущий никакой ценности к тому, что было сказано выше.


При не знании ответа на простой вопрос мне помогает ChatGPT или поиск вопроса в поисковой системе.
ChatGPT и проще найти ответ в поисковике, чем ждать сутки пока тебе ответят.
Добавьте возможность не только задавать вопросы, но и делиться своими проектами на вашей платформе, писать статьи, пускай в текстовом формате на подобии Дзена, а не GitHub. Так можно будет создавать обсуждения вопросов вокруг своего проекта, спрашивать у заинтересованных людей что им было бы интересно добавить, проводить тестирования проекта. Пора перерасти из простого Q&A в полноценную "соцсеть", "хаб" для программистов


Правильно, "хаб" для программистов выглядит намного лучше, чем "база знаний"

tl;dr: новый продукт, Q&A как формат в моих глазах себя изжил, и я не верю, что компания такой продукт сделает
Уж извините, я на все пункты отвечу одним ответом, т. к. в моём случае они образуют систему, которую я затрудняюсь разделить так, чтобы имело смысл голосовать за одну часть без других.
Привет! Особенно тем, кто меня тут ещё помнит. Тем, кто не помнит, краткая историческая справка: я самоудалился с сайта (и на прощание отправил багрепорт по этому процессу) после одной из крупных драм вокруг явной дыры в самоуправлении сообщества. Известен я тут был как D-side и отвечал в основном в ruby и тут, на Мете. Что я успел понаписать в свою бытность здесь, можно найти по ссылкам, которые я собрал в архив у себя на сайте (ru.SO и Мета).
Ключевых причин для ухода у меня было три:
1. Крах «самоуправления» на ru.SO
Я рассматривал свою деятельность на сайте как общественно-просветительскую, и за сим считал ключевой особенностью сайта механизмы самоуправления для его сообщества, через которые сайт нёс какую-никакую ответственность перед обществом, в просвещении которого участвует.
Когда администрация сообщества (возглавляемая на тот момент Николасом, и никто в участии в этом беспорядке прямо не признался) начала произвольно наказывать пользователей по сомнительным поводам, всячески отмалчиваясь во всех официальных каналах, стало ясно, что моё видение роли сайта в общественной жизни не совпадает с видением компании и отношения со старожилами дальше будут только портиться, поэтому я решил этого не дожидаться и уйти, прежде чем дальнейшие действия меня расстроят только сильнее. Потому что я не железный, извините.
2. Владение инфраструктурой
Где-то тогда же начался конфликт вокруг внезапного безответственного разжалования общественно избранного модератора Моники, дошедший аж до юридической тяжбы с соглашением-кляпом, запрещающим сторонам рассказывать какие-либо подробности. Прозрачность так и прёт, извините за выражение.
Где-то тогда я начал задумываться о том, что идеалы самоуправления сообщества, которых я ожидал в п. 1, невозможны на текущей инфраструктуре, полностью принадлежащей SO, поскольку при централизованном владении инфраструктурой неизбежно образуются конфликты интересов между владельцем инфраструктуры и пользующейся ею общественностью. Что реальное самоуправление возможно лишь тогда, когда инфраструктура принадлежит общественности и решениям от любых ключевых лиц можно хоть на каком-то уровне противостоять, не теряя систему полностью (частично можно).
Эта проблема, увы, не уникальна для Stack Overflow, и насколько я могу судить, её решением вяленько занимается всего несколько коллективов в условиях довольно жёсткой нехватки ресурсов, в том числе самого главного — пользователей. Но прогресс есть, правда больше не в Q&A, а в соцсетях, уже много лет как существует Fediverse, объединение общающихся между собой ресурсов, где каждый устанавливает и приводит в исполнение собственные правила, карательные решения действуют только там где их приняли и где с ними согласились и у инфраструктуры этих ресурсов нет общего владельца, создать собственный ресурс (узел, инстанс) может каждый.
Может, когда-нибудь кто-нибудь натянет на эту модель и SE-подобный Q&A. Но пока ещё даже с представлением социальной активности там не всё гладко. Тем не менее, там уже сейчас работает та часть, которая мне в этом эксперименте наиболее интересна — реальное локальное самоуправление.
3. Ограниченность формата Q&A
Мне просто надоело отвечать тут на вопросы. Но в результате длительной рефлексии я напал на куда более осязаемый след, чем просто субъективное ощущение, что "расхотелось".
Самым болезненным намёком на эту проблему для меня стал вопрос о "спинизах" (спины тут ни при чём, это "списки навыков и знаний"), и этот вид материалов как следует не помещался не только сюда, но и вообще куда-либо. Это стало для меня ярким проявлением симптома гораздо более глубокой проблемы — публикуемые здесь ответы не складываются в систему, поэтому их сложно использовать повторно, ведь чтобы два читателя в равной степени поняли один и тот же ответ, у них должен предварительно быть какой-то общий пласт знаний, чтобы этот ответ воспринять и наложить на свою ситуацию (и последнее будет нетривиальной операцией как минимум для одного из читателей, если исходно ответ написан для другого).
В компании Stack Overflow, кстати, тоже это семейство проблем заметили, решили что его получится решить посредством банального wiki-проекта под эгидой SO, в результате чего открылся (и вскоре закрылся) Stack Overflow Documentation. У него были очень сильные стороны, самым сильным из которых я считаю крупное сообщество мотивированных авторов (с мотивацией примерно как в п. 1), но не взлетело.
Решение проблемы, которое я начал набрасывать (не на вентилятор, а наброски делать) ещё под тем вопросом, прошло много итераций и очень сильно упростилось, но дальше локального прототипа всё ещё не зашло по целому ряду причин (жизненные обстоятельства, состояние фронтендного инструментария, нехватка ряда специальных навыков). Я не знаю, что будет с этим проектом дальше, но он у меня в списке приоритетов на уделение времени сейчас находится выше, чем ответы на ru.SO, на ru.SO попросту не остаётся времени.

Итог
Я считаю, что формат Q&A Stack Overflow неизбежно загоняет меня, как активного отвечающего, во множество небольших кругов, в которых я объясняю более-менее одно и то же много раз и не могу выстроить структуру, с помощью которой отвечающие могли бы отвечать не только на свой непосредственный вопрос, но и на те, которые у них могут возникнуть в процессе прочтения непосредственно присланного, чем экономили бы моё время на поиск ссылок на нужную им информацию. Механизм дубликатов помогает, но совсем чуть-чуть. Механизм связанных вопросов слишком примитивен, чтобы помогать в этом.
Я на дух не переношу повторяющуюся деятельность, она вгоняет меня в глубокую тоску. Мне становится из-за неё скучно и я просто перестаю этим заниматься. По жизни это тоже мешает, увы, но мириться с этим я не научился.
Причина моего ухода растёт из самых концептуальных основ сайта и что-то с ней сделать, боюсь, может только новый продукт. И я не верю, что Stack Overflow как компания способна сделать этот продукт без неприемлемых для меня этических компромиссов (п. 1 и 2).
Проблема, которую я надеюсь решить (п. 3), огромна. Я хотел бы создать формат, который заменит или как минимум дополнит статьи, книги, руководства (how-tos) и дорожные карты (roadmaps). SO делает что может в устоявшихся форматах. После Documentation у меня такое ощущение, что новые форматы компания искать прекратила. Но признаюсь, я не слишком внимательно слежу, может я и неправ. Да и SO как коммерческое предприятие не обязано кому попало рассказывать обо всех инициативах дальнейшего развития.
Чёрт, я не уверен даже, что такой продукт в нынешней социоэкономической структуре в принципе реализуем — должен отдать Stack Overflow должное, финансовые вопросы они успешно закрывают, обеспечивая функционирование ресурса. То, что я критикую настолько основополагающие принципы SO, растут вовсе не из пожеланий ему гибели. Таких у меня нет, на мой взгляд такое частичное решение проблемы распространения знаний о программировании гораздо полезнее его отсутствия.
Просто мне кажется, что существующий уровень функционирования вполне смогут обеспечить другие участники, а мне будет полезнее заняться тем, чем другие вряд ли займутся. Пока на это есть хоть какие-то ресурсы. Они, к сожалению, не бесконечны.
Я допускаю, что могу вернуться, если моя идея всё же доживёт до испытания боем и рассыпется на ещё более мелкие кусочки, чем SO Documentation. Но это настолько далёкий горизонт, что туда смотреть сегодня я бы даже не пытался.
Я не берусь утверждать, что такой настрой в конечном счёте будет настигать старожилов ресурса сколько-нибудь массово. Но и сильно сомневаюсь, что мой случай уникален. Если я прав, то для сохранения активности нужно обращать новичков в активных участников быстрее, чем старожилы сталкиваются с вышеописанной проблемой и уходят. Поскольку я уже много лет сам не являюсь активным участником, то не очень представляю, как это сегодня происходит, а догадки строить не возьмусь.

Компания не прекратила искать, см. "Дискуссии" на английском стеке. Но результат поисков плачевный: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/431693/8674428

@SmallSoft с ребрендингом! Мда-а. На новый формат это не очень похоже, если честно, я имел в виду глобально новый, а не для компании. Даже забавно, что SO/SE вроде как вырос из отрицания форумов, а теперь, видимо растеряв дух основателей, стучится обратно.

Лет восемь назад я впервые узнал про ru.SO, зайдя сюда по приглашению, присланному по email через английский SO. Меня радовал ru.SO, и лет пять я более-менее активно участвовал, получил несколько толковых ответов на свои вопросы и иногда отвечал, хотя и не очень активно. Это приносило как удовлетворение ("людям помогаю"), так и пользу мне самому -- узнавал новое, четче понимал то, что знаю. Короче говоря, участие было и приятным, и полезным.
Но лет пять назад политика стала постепенно меняться. Приоритет стал отдаваться популярности в ущерб качеству. Сообщество и модераторы стали терпимее относиться к просьбам решить домашку, к вопросам, которые явно демонстрировали нежелание автора приложить какие-то собственные усилия для решения вопроса, нежелание напрячься и сформулировать мысль, нежелание учиться.
С другой стороны, не порицались ответы откровенно низкого качества, и ответы на такие вопросы, на которые отвечать не стоит (решить домашку и т.п.), часто было видно, что человек отвечает только ради рейтинга, не всегда понимая даже смысл вопроса. В результате средний уровень как вопросов, так и ответов заметно упал.
Мне еще тогда казалось, что такая политика может оказаться контрпродуктивной -- вместо роста популярности можно было получить падение качества и, как результат, отток знающих людей, снижение вероятности получения полезного ответа и падение посещаемости. Меня это тревожило, мне небезразлична была судьба ru.SO. Я несколько раз брался говорить об этом здесь, на мете, но большинство участников (или по крайней мере модераторы) со мной или не соглашались, или просто не понимали, о чем я говорю.
В конечном счете мне стало просто неинтересно и последние года три я практически не заходил сюда; хорошо если за три года пять раз заходил и на три вопроса ответил.
Однако, мне все еще обидно за ru.SO, который так хорошо начинался, поэтому, случайно  вот сегодня заглянув и увидев в "Важном" этот вопрос, я и пишу всё это.
Ну и собственно ответы на вопросы.
> Почему вы стали реже использовать ru.SO?

Процент интересных вопросов упал, а с учётом падения посещаемости их стало совсем мало. Скучно просматривать массу дурацких вопросов и не хочется помогать тем, кто сам не хочет приложить никаких усилий.
Шансы получить полезный ответ на свой вопрос сильно снизились.

> Какие факторы, на ваш взгляд, повлияли на снижение активности?

ChatGPT и ему подобное.
Отток специалистов из России и их ускоренная интеграция в мировое IT-community, c переходом на английский SO
Политика, фактически поощряющая снижение качества контента ru.SO

> Какой формат привлечения пользователей был бы полезен?

Хорошо сформулированная вводная страница, которая принудительно показывается новым пользователям. С кратким, но ясным списком прелестей SO и с советами, как и какие вопросы задавать стоит, а как и какие не стоит, со ссылками на страницы справки про хорошие вопросы и т. п. Может быть, специально написать несколько таких страниц, кратко и доходчиво. Новички по началу часто просто не понимают, куда они попали и как тут себя вести. По себе помню.
Может быть, принять какие-то меры из области поисковой оптимизации, но я в этом ничего не смыслю.
Попробовать договориться о рекламе ru.SO с какими-то дружественными ресурсами
Завести канал в телеграме


Никак.
За 10 лет можно было бы понять, что этот сайт в первую очередь ориентирован на людей, приходящих за готовыми ответами из поиска. Просто потому что тупо в тысячи раз больше.
Но местные "модераторы" и "контрибьюторы" до сих пор считают эту простую мысль чудовищной ересью. А сайт видят этаким кладбищем торопливых неграмотных ответов на дурацкие вопросы, где ответ имеет только одну цель - стоять незыблемым монументом, чтобы к нему мог приходить автор, полюбоваться на свои виртуальные достижения.
И даже если абсолютно нелепому вопросу удалось выиграть в лотерею и совпасть с популярным поисковым запросом, и он начинает приводить таки на сайт многотысячный трафик - при этом редактировать и вопрос, и ответы на него, чтобы сделать их осмысленными и полезными приходящим из поиска посетителям, запрещают запредельно нелепый свод "правил". И этот трафик, покрутив рукой у виска, уходит на другие ресурсы.
С таким подходом опрос надо устраивать не на тему "как вернуть активность" а "как скоро тут останутся только модераторы в полном одиночестве".

Насколько мне известно, если автор удалён, давно не заходил, то мы можем делать ответ "осмысленным" при условии, что он становится "общим". Я так уже редактировала ответ. И модераторы посмотрев, принимают. Главное, чтоб "осмысленность" совпадала. Порой лучше добавить новый ответ, если изменения сильно отличаются от оригинала.

Это точно должны делать не модераторы. Модераторам таких полномочий никто не давал, хотя в PII емейл и показывается.

Как насчет метки [важное]? Вопрос вроде вменяемо сформулирован, сгодится для блока Важное на мете. А емейл может и не нужен, как уже отметили, народ их не читает.

@MSDN.WhiteKnight [важное] имеет смысл вешать, когда внимания недостаточно и хочется больше. Сейчас вопрос и без этого попал в список "Обсуждаемое на Мете", т.е. получает дополнительные просмотры.
