# Почему участник, который модератор в другом SO сообществе, в чате ruSO показывается как модератор?

Tags: поддержка, модерация, чат

Для меня лично странно что [участник](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/users/20688/anton-menshov), который в [ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/337980/anton-menshov) и в [ruSO Meta](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/337980/anton-menshov) не отображается как модератор, в [чатах ruSO](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62730234#62730234) отображается как модератор

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не знаю это ошибка или так задумано

Если это не ошибка, то объясните пожалуйста причину такой логики отображения

Если это ошибка, то предлагаю отображать модератора как модератора только в чатах, в сообществах которых он - модератор

Comment: [Связанный вопрос на ruSO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7683/337980)

Comment: если кратко, то модерация чата производится модераторами всех сообществ и разделения нет. Любой модератор любого сообщества будет показан как модератор в чате. Это предложение поднималось на общей мете (не могу найти сразу), и требует значительного изменения механики.

Comment: @AntonMenshov чаты MSE в этом плане вроде бы особенные.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ да, есть некоторое разделение, но оно немасштабируемо в текущей форме - от слова "вообще". Кстати еще есть недавняя модификация, которая позволяет мне не быть модератором в Teacher's Lounge (общем модераторском чате) — раньше и это было не так и возникали некоторые конфликты (не со мной, если что :) ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чаты не привязаны к какому-ту конкретному сообществу. К примеру чтобы получить доступ к чату нужно иметь минимум 20 репутации на любом из сайтов сети.

А еще, насколько мне известно, любой модератор может модерировать чат.

Comment: [источник](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87761/383809), раздел посвященный ♦︎ moderator и [общий FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/100153/383809) c простым упоминанием, что "Site moderators are also chat moderators."