# Что такое Code of Conduct и как он будет работать?

Tags: поддержка, нормы-поведения

Видя накал страстей в чате, очевидно, что тема очень и очень важная и чувствительная для многих участников, глубоко неравнодушных к ruSO, как по самой сути принятого [Code of Conduct](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct), так и по тому, *как* подобные изменения будут приниматься и попадать на ruSO "сверху" в дальнейшем.

Это открытый вопрос <s>к @NicolasChabanovsky</s> (судя по его [ответам](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46174344#46174344) [в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46174607#46174607), он за это не отвечает), к администрации и модераторам ruSO с просьбой, сделать пожалуйста пост на Мете про новый [Code of Conduct](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct):

- что он такое,
- для чего нужен,
- кто и зачем его писал,
- насколько верен его перевод и может ли он быть дополнен/улучшен,
- как он влияет на ruSO и участников,
- (запрещает ли он сарказм)
- как им следует руководствоваться участникам,
- как им будут руководствоваться модераторы,
- будет ли он источником новых банов,
- каковы возможности по его изменению (демократически или как-то иначе),
- бонус, как сообщество сможет повлиять на некий будущий CoC2.0 (с еще более спорными рекомендациями/правилами (например, запретят гендерные обращения))

Уже больше недели идет обсуждение деталей принятого Code of Conduct (в т.ч. [Стоит ли нам полностью запретить иронию и сарказм на сайте?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7593)), и в то же время, **до сих пор нет официальной позиции** от представителей администрации.

Answer (score 5):

> **TL; DR**: Ничего особо не меняется и это хорошо.

Я не Николас, а рядовой участник сообщества, но с учётом того, что Николас упрямо настаивает на позиции, что на мете нет вопросов, которые могут быть адресованы лично одному человеку (даже если это представитель администрации), то я отвечу так, как вижу ответ на эти вопросы.

> Я понимаю, что вы бы хотели адресовать вопрос администрации. Вполне
>   логично. Дело в том, что на SO другой подход к публикации вопросов на
>   Мете. **Если вы хотите ответ от администрации, вы можете задать вопрос
>   через форму обратной связи**. На мой взгляд, модераторы (кто–либо из
>   них) часто могут лучше меня разобраться в каком–то вопросе. Я не вижу
>   причин, зачем не давать им возможность поделиться идеями.
>
> Если хотите получить ответ раньше сентября, пожалуйста, адресуйте его
>   всем. В этом случае, тот, кто разобрался ответит вам в самое ближайшее
>   время.
>
> Повторюсь, сделайте ваш вопрос соответствующим модели публикации
>   вопросов на SO. Вопросы не могут быть адресованы одному участнику. Они
>   задаются всем.

Предвижу заранее негатив, что не тот человек ответил и что ответы совершенно не те, которые ожидаются. Ну, из песни слов не выкинешь.

> что он такое

CoC -- это документ, который описывает философию поведения, которое рекомендуется участникам и прописывает общими словами механизмы которыми может воспользоваться участник, если видит нарушения (флаги + форма обратной связи + институт модераторов).

> для чего нужен

Документ является "рамочным" и "высокоуровневым", там написано общими словами за всё хорошее против всего плохого.

Поэтому практически каждый человек согласится, что документ неплохой и подпишется практически под каждым его словом. (Ну вот разве [с иронией возникали вопросы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7593/213987) и в русском сообществе и в английском: некоторым кажется, что ирония - это хороший коммуникационный приём)

Для чего нужны такие общие документы? Для того, чтобы использовать. Это не какой-то конкретный список стоп-слов, за которые будут банить модераторы, это просто постулирование: у нас есть институт модераторов, они решают вопросы.

Там нет никаких подробностей, что это за модераторы (их сейчас избирают, но об этом ничего не сказано), там нет подробностей о конкретных вариантов за что можно поставить флаг (и они периодически неожиданно меняются).

И это даёт гибкость: можно не меняя документ ввести новые опций за что флагать или перестать выбирать модераторов, а назначать их по представлению менеджера сообщества. Какие-то темы нужно смотреть в других документах, они там раскрыты более подробно, какие-то темы вряд ли будут раскрыты, например список матерных слов. (тот самый аргумент про "оскорбить можно любым словом").

> кто и зачем его писал

Написан он владельцами сайта stackoverflow и отражает их вИдение идеального сообщества. Фактически, этот документ должен был стать заменой ныне удалённого документа [be-nice](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/be-nice). (Я лично не вижу особого повода для замены: и прошлый и текущий содержали настолько прекраснодушные абстракции, что под них можно подогнать всё, что угодно.)

Я подчеркну, что правила сайта пишутся только владельцами сайта и что компания старается учесть обратную связь от некоторых пользователей. [Правила - это фундаментальная вещь](http://www.adolgin.ru/online/) и как только они меняются неизбежно найдутся те, кому новые правила не подходят и кто хочет чтобы остались старые.

Компания старается учесть это:

- CoC писался по материалам, которые получала в течение нескольких лет работы be nice;
- кроме того черновик документа обсуждался с сообществом на английской мете и мы к сожалению не успевали по срокам, но попытались [устроить обсуждение черновика](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7552/213987) на русской - Николас пригласил к обсуждению 26го числа, а 27го уже срок заканчивался, ну и поиск добровольцев и перевод был не мгновенным)

Но всё же необходимо понимать, что компания не обязана пытаться соблюсти все до единого интереса (бесконечное число участников привести к единым правилам будет бесконечно сложно из-за наличия противоречащих установок).

И нужно понимать, что хотя вероятно будут приняты меры по минимизации ухода пользователей (их два: сбор обратной связи + обтекаемость формулировок), но всех удержать не получится. Вероятно, тут расчёт на то, что уйдёт десяток троллей, но взамен придут сотни и тысячи хороших участников. Так ли это или расчёт не оправдается -- покажет время, но повлиять на это вряд ли возможно, не будучи владельцем сайта.

> насколько верен его перевод и может ли он быть дополнен/улучшен

Перевод выполнялся добровольцем @Arhad, после чего допиливался другими добровольцами, среди которых отдельной строкой выделю @Aer, который является [избранным модератором сообщества Русский язык](https://rus.stackexchange.com/).

Сама администрация не имеет выделенных переводчиков специально для перевода уставных документов, это делается волонтёрами на добровольной основе и это никогда не влияло на статус документов. Да, основной язык правил - английский, а не русский и в случае разночтений приоритет будет отдан всегда английской версии -- но этот момент стараются учесть при переводе.

Может ли быть улучшен перевод? Разумеется может. Для этого переводы публикуются на мете, где происходит обсуждение и редактура, любой участник может принять участие в этом процессе. Есть некоторый процесс, защищающий от вандализма при переводе, перевод не появляется мгновенно на сайте, там несколько ступеней.

> как он влияет на ruSO и участников

Каждый сайт сети stackexchange подчиняется общим правилам сети и CoC - один из таких документов. Создавать индивидуальные правила для каждого сайта влечёт большие накладные расходы на создание и сопровождение сайта для его владельцев, поэтому правила унифицированы.

Насколько мне известно нет никаких локальных правил сообществ, которые бы отменяли действие глобальных правил, нет "автономии правил". Как описывал ситуацию КМ Николас - то, что обсуждается на мете не носит характер правил сообщества, это т.н. "[инициативы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6835/213987)", которые не могут даже в теории противоречить глобальным правилам, да и вообще не обязаны быть приняты в расчёт владельцами по любой причине, например по вполне разумной "это дорого и не окупится".

Процитирую кратко:

> Вопросы управления сайтом и сообществом ... делятся на:
>
> - Вопросы, решения в которых принимают участники демократически.
> - Вопросы, решения в которых принимает компания единолично, опираясь на отзывы сообщества.

Заинтересовавшимся дам пару ссылок на темы, в которых это затрагивалось:

- [Границы демократических процедур](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7221/213987)
- [Альтернативный регламент для инициатив](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6899/213987)
- [Праймериз для инициатив](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6876/213987)

Соответственно, CoC влияет на жизнь участников ruSO самым непосредственным образом: можно про CoC ничего не знать, но тем не менее он регламентирует один из важных столпов сообщества.

Немногие видят сайт в реальном времени и есть оперативное модерирование сайта, которое вычищает значительную часть неприемлемого контента (флаги участников, действия автоматических скриптов и действия модераторов).

И это в общем-то хорошо, даёт чистый сайт с минимизацией усилий.

Что делать, если под каток правил попали вы сами?

Ну во-первых, именно в этот момент вы можете впервые узнать о существовании CoC (и прекратить пользоваться сайтом, если не согласны с его положениями -- и напомню, что незнание закона не освобождает от ответственности за его невыполнение: увы, но надо читать мелкий шрифт, когда соглашаешься с при регистрации ну и всё такое)

А во-вторых, в том же CoC заложены механизмы, что делать если вы считаете, что под каток попали по ошибке: пишите через форму обратной связи.

> (запрещает ли он сарказм)

Это очень распространённое опасение, даже несмотря на то, что в формулировках по-максимуму используются слова, которые несут оттенок рекомендации и избегают явного запрета.

Увы, но опасения и страхи вещь иррациональная и бороться с этим можно только долгой работой и разъяснениями.

Я [создал обсуждение этого вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7593/213987), так как он волновал значимых для меня знакомых в сообществе и получил вполне устраивающий меня ответ. В теме есть два мнения от действующих избранных модераторов (которые являются частью того самого института модерирования). Первый говорит о том, что хотел бы чтобы иронию не запрещали (читаем между строк: а если запретят - придётся выполнять), второй прямо говорит, что новый CoC не запрещает иронию.

Мне этого показалось вполне достаточно, что текущий модсостав не видит в этих правилах запрета на иронию. Что будет в будущем - не знаю, я не гадалка, но хочу напомнить, что выбор модераторов определяется голосами участников. Участвуйте в выборах, изучайте позицию модераторов, выбирайте лучших на ваш взгляд!

> как им следует руководствоваться участникам

Ну как, как... нагорную проповедь читали? Ну вот и живите так: не крадите, не убивайте, ведите себя дружелюбно - и будет вам щасстье. Кому нравится грабить корованы, троллить и розжигать флейм - кнопка выход вверху справа.

Ну и немного серьёзности. Поделюсь двумя наблюдениями.

Во-первых, не замыкайтесь только на этом сайте, живите почаще полноценной жизнью в оффлайне. Некоторые, кто мониторит сайт в режиме реального времени, мне кажется устают видеть неприемлемый контент и через некоторое время не видят ничего плохого чтобы ответить злом на зло, оком на око. Ну а поскольку убийства, оскорбления запрещены - то подавляя эту агрессию (ну вы поняли buzzword который я хотел процитировать: "пассивная агрессия") участник доходит до... ну да, до иронии.

Во-вторых, мне иногда кажется, что некоторые участники изначально приходя на сайт придумают себе фабулу "я пришёл сюда спасать мир", потом придумывают некоторые правила "я спасу тебя только если ты <сделаешь то-то и так-то>", потом когда не увидят этого в вопросе начинают испытывать злость и раздражение. Примеры если кому интересно могут всплыть в чате, на мете, но рассчитываю, что их вам искать не стоит. И да, там же я давал рецепт:

> Так лучше НАКАЖИТЕ спрашивающего тем, что просто не дадите ответ. Это
>   уже само по себе страшное наказание, а уже если закрыть право на ответ
>   или минусом закрыть право задавать новые вопросы...

В остальном же: поступайте как участник так, как вам хочется, в пределах правил вы вольны делать всё, что пожелаете. Свобода и демократия, все дела.

> как им будут руководствоваться модераторы

Во-первых, я хочу процитировать слова одного очень уважаемого мной модератора:

> т.е. если у нас в общесетевых правилах написано "осторожно с
>   сарказмом" - то это просто рекомендация. Если на мете на предложение
>   "запретить сарказм?" наголосуют "запретить сарказм и всем говорить
>   Сэр" - моды будут форсить именно этот вариант. Если наголосуют
>   "сарказм разрешен" - моды скажут "ну ок", и будут, как и раньше
>   руководстоваться "будьте дружелюбными", и вежливо просить нарушителей
>   (тех, кто совсем злобно сарказм проявляет) перестать.

Здесь говорится о двух вещах: что модераторы [обязаны соблюдать правила](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement), поэтому старайтесь наголосовывать правила для модераторов с умом и не играть со спичками, которыми сами можете обжечься. И о том, что следует различать "рекомендацию" и "обязанность".

Во-вторых, я хочу напомнить, что помимо CoC есть и другие документы, которые регламентируют правила сайта. Например по модерации есть [Теория модерации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7420/213987), возможно и другие документы. Вот нашлось ещё: [Справка > Репутация и модерация > Кто такие модераторы и какова их роль?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)

Плюс, давайте по-честному: в модераторы у нас на сайте выбирают пользователей с максимальной репутацией, кто уже многое время по факту выполнял работу модератора. Помните, даже вопрос есть "а зачем вам ромб, раз  ничего особо не поменяется в доступных инструментах"? Так что есть сложившаяся практика модерации i mean "преемственность": вы с чистого листа приходите в модераторы, в любой времени у нас есть набор действующих модераторов, кто продолжает работать, пока вы входите в курс дел, у нас есть база знаний - мета, где можно почитать кейсы прошлых модераторов; у нас есть кадровый резерв в виде большой пирамиды участников, кто только осваивает сайт и набирает опыт, ответы, репутацию.

> будет ли он источником новых банов

Лично я не вижу никаких новых источников. Ругань, мат и прочие плохие вещи были и при старом be nice запрещены, этих источников вполне много.

Разумеется, уже произошли некоторые изменения в текстовках флагов, но кардинально там ничего не поменялось.

А посадки - будут. И раньше были и сейчас будут. Подразумевается, что без этой скверны на сайте будет лучше и это даст прирост трафика, посетителей и всеобщего хэппенинга.

> каковы возможности по его изменению (демократически или как-то иначе),

Перечитайте ещё раз (выше) фразу "Вопросы управления сайтом и сообществом ... делятся на: ....Вопросы, решения в которых принимает компания единолично, опираясь на отзывы сообщества." CoC - как раз из этой категории вопросов.

> как сообщество сможет повлиять на некий будущий CoC2.0

Можете попробовать:

- создавать темы на мете по вопросам, которые вас волнуют (администрация их рассматривает как некоторую обратную связь и декларирует, что использует в своих последующих работах).
- если вы не метаписатель - активно выражайте свою позицию плюсиками, хотя в последнее время и администрация и модераторы акцентируют внимание на то, что непонятно, что хотели сказать плюсиками-минусиками и нужен ответ из букавак.
- если у вас всё в порядке с английским - то помогайте переводом острых тем с английской меты, либо хотя бы просто нотифицируйте о новостях, что там в большом мире происходит. У нас острая нехватка рук именно в вопросе "нам бы дайджест с en меты": ни у модераторов нет рук на это, ни у администрации. (Выше пример, как мы прошляпили сроки по обсуждению CoC)
- также если у вас хороший английский можно пушить острые темы с русской меты обратно на английскую

Как-то так. Надеюсь, что помог прояснить ваши вопросы.

Бонусы. Ответы на незаданные но смежные вопросы.

Вижу одной из задач КМ/администрации доносить до людей смысл изменений, пояснять как это будет работать, отвечать на вопросы. Уклонение от этой обязанности [считаю](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46175994#46175994) попыткой оставить себе слишком значительное поле для манёвра (люди будут писать ответы вместо администрации, думая, что они что-то решают - но в любой момент, когда вдруг администрации перестанет нравится происходящее администратор просто скажет "нет, вы не так поняли" и перечеркнёт любое количество накопленного социального капитала).

Хочу напомнить, что именно подобное поведение неизбежно привело к тому, что некоторые участники обманулись в своих ожиданиях что so является демократией и именно это привело нас к одному из самых масштабных кризисов русского сайта за всё время, которое повлекло уход пользователя являющегося лидером по репутации (ТОП-1).

Напоминаю – и на основании прошлого опыта предостерегаю от повторения подобного в будущем:

Неопределённость является отличнейшей питательной средой для роста непонимания, страха, недоверия у участников и это просто неприемлемо!

Answer (score 1):

В ожидании ответов от администрации и модераторского состава, вот очевидные ответы (следующие из прочтения искомого документа) и резюме ответов представителя администрации из чата (со ссылками):

> что он такое
>   для чего нужен

Это расширение ранее существовавшей политики дружелюбия (т.н. "бинайс"), теперь с примерами. Направлен на улучшение качества пребывания всех посетителей на сайтах SE.

> кто и зачем его писал

компания при участии фидбэка от пользователей ([часть 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312038/wed-like-your-feedback-on-our-new-code-of-conduct), [часть 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312850/the-second-draft-of-our-code-of-conduct-is-available-for-feedback-and-review))

> насколько верен его перевод и может ли он быть дополнен/улучшен

это открытый вопрос, т.к. перевод фактически еще не точен

> как он влияет на ruSO и участников

по идее, никак. Просто чётче обозначает, что такое дружелюбие

> (запрещает ли он сарказм)

Рекомендует воздерживаться от сарказма и иронии, т.к. они могут быть восприняты негативно другими посетителями

> как им следует руководствоваться участникам

Принимать во внимание и стараться следовать рекоммендациям из него. Как и ранее, привлекать внимание модераторов к спорным случаям (нарушения правил и норм общения).

> как им следует руководствоваться модераторам

Принимать во внимание, стараться следовать рекоммендациям из него лично и реагировать на тревоги от участников. Документ рекомендует решать большинство проблем выдачей "предупреждений".

> будет ли он источником новых банов

В отношении **участников**, решение за модераторами
[Если **модераторы** будут нарушать правила, то они будут сняты.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46174660#46174660)
Например, пост про [Процедуру снятия модератора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28867/what-recourse-do-i-have-if-i-believe-a-moderator-has-abused-his-her-privileges)

> каковы возможности по его изменению (демократически или как-то иначе)

Скорее всего, только через [главную Мету](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)

> как сообщество сможет повлиять на некий будущий CoC2.0 (с еще более спорными рекомендациями/правилами (например, запретят гендерные обращения))

Теоретически - через [главную Мету](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), создав заявку и привлекая к ней голоса и внимание. Реалистично - никак.